# What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?

Tags: string, rust

Why does Rust have both [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) and [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html)? What are the differences between them, and when should one be used over the other? Is one of them getting deprecated?

Answer (score 1152, accepted):

`String` is the dynamic heap string type, like `Vec`: use it when you need to own or modify your string data.

`str` is an immutable<sup>1</sup> sequence of UTF-8 bytes of dynamic length somewhere in memory. Since the size is unknown, one can only handle it behind a pointer. This means that `str` most commonly<sup>2</sup> appears as `&str`: a reference to some UTF-8 data, normally called a "string slice" or just a "slice". [A slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) is just a view onto some data, and that data can be anywhere, e.g.

- **In static storage**: a string literal `"foo"` is a `&'static str`. The data is hardcoded into the executable and loaded into memory when the program runs.
- **Inside a heap allocated `String`**: [`String` dereferences to a `&str` view](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref) of the `String`'s data.
- **On the stack**: e.g. the following creates a stack-allocated byte array, and then gets a [view of that data as a `&str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html):

  ```
  use std::str;

  let x: [u8; 3] = [b'a', b'b', b'c'];
  let stack_str: &str = str::from_utf8(&x).unwrap();
  ```

In summary, use `String` if you need owned string data (like passing strings to other threads, or building them at runtime), and use `&str` if you only need a view of a string.

This is identical to the relationship between a vector `Vec<T>` and a slice `&[T]`, and is similar to the relationship between by-value `T` and by-reference `&T` for general types.

---

<sup>1</sup> A `str` is fixed-length; you cannot write bytes beyond the end, or leave trailing invalid bytes. Since UTF-8 is a variable-width encoding, this effectively forces all `str`s to be immutable in many cases. In general, mutation requires writing more or fewer bytes than there were before (e.g. replacing an `a` (1 byte) with an `ä` (2+ bytes) would require making more room in the `str`). There are specific methods that can modify a `&mut str` in place, mostly those that handle only ASCII characters, like [`make_ascii_uppercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.make_ascii_uppercase).

<sup>2</sup> [Dynamically sized types](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/01/05/dst-take-5/) allow things like `Rc<str>` for a sequence of reference counted UTF-8 bytes since Rust 1.2. Rust 1.21 allows easily creating these types.

Comment: "sequence of UTF-8 bytes (**of unknown length**)" - is this out of date? The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.str.html) say "A `&str` is made up of two components: a pointer to some bytes, and a length."

Comment: It's not out of date (that representation has been fairly stable), just a little imprecise: it isn't statically known, unlike, say, `[u8; N]`.

Comment: @mrec it's unknown at compile time, assumptions about it size can not be made, for example, when creating a stack frame.

Thus why it's often treated as a reference, which a reference is a known size at compile time, which is the size of a pointer.

Comment: Update: `Rc<str>` and `Arc<str>` are now usable via the standard library.

Comment: > "In static storage: a string literal "foo" is a &'static str. The data is hardcoded into the executable and loaded into memory when the program runs." --- should explain in what memory it is loaded. Like if it's stored on the heap or stack or somewhere else

Comment: @cjohansson Statically allocated objects are normally stored neither on the heap, nor the stack, but in their own region of memory.

Comment: If I keep a reference to a string slice and the original `String` gets out of scope, the slice keeps the entire original string value in memory, right? (the question probably makes more sense when thinking of a slice as a substring).

Comment: @lxx, no, Rust's ownership and borrowing kicks in: the compiler won't let you hold a `&str` slice pointing into a `String` that goes out of scope and is deallocated. In a garbage collected language the slice can exist after the main owner disappears, but in Rust it cannot: the compiler forces the programmer to explicitly choose how to handle it, e.g. don't share memory (by using `.to_owned()` to make a separate `String`), or share memory like you say (by using something like http://kimundi.github.io/owning-ref-rs/owning_ref/index.html#caching-a-subslice-of-a-string ).

Comment: "an immutable sequence of dynamic length" sounds a bit contradictory for me. It seems dynamic means here something that opposed to such types as u32, etc., i.e. we always know the length of every u32 value, but not every str . Have I got it right?

Comment: How it comes out we don't know a str length but is aware of a length of data which a pointer points to? Btw, why can't a program get str length information run-time?

Comment: @Mergasov yeah, you're right. The "dynamic" means that it's only known at runtime in general (the `.len()` method returns it). The opposite of dynamic is "static", which you are right about too: a type like `u32` has a statically known size of 4, while the type `str` does not (there's know way to know how many bytes are in an arbitrary value of type `str`)

Answer (score 264):

I have a C++ background and I found it very useful to think about `String` and `&str` in C++ terms:

- A Rust `String` is like a `std::string`; it owns the memory and does the dirty job of managing memory.
- A Rust `&str` is like a `char*` (but a little more sophisticated); it points us to the beginning of a chunk in the same way you can get a pointer to the contents of `std::string`.

Are either of them going to disappear? I do not think so. They serve two purposes:

`String` keeps the buffer and is very practical to use. `&str` is lightweight and should be used to "look" into strings. You can search, split, parse, and even replace chunks without needing to allocate new memory.

`&str` can look inside of a `String` as it can point to some string literal. The following code needs to copy the literal string into the `String` managed memory:

```
let a: String = "hello rust".into();
```

The following code lets you use the literal itself without a copy (read-only though):

```
let a: &str = "hello rust";
```

Comment: like a string_view?

Comment: Yes like string_view but intrinsic to the language and properly borrow checked.

Comment: `string_view` is an abomination. Imagine `auto_ptr<T>` level bad.

Comment: Why can't I println!() a &str without formatting it into a literal? In C I can do printf(name_of_c_string);

Comment: @IsaacD.Cohen I guess that you mean why must the format string of println! be a literal and not a pointer/slice or any other reference to an existing string? 
I guess the answer is rather philosophical, but there are good reasons to do so: you may want to keep the format string static so that the compiler can verify things like the number of arguments, and avoid runtime surprises. Notice that C allows it because the format string is a pointer to char. This is not an advantage, it is a flaw resulting from C being semi-strongly typed and other typing issues. After all, C is universal assembly.

Answer (score 155):

It is `str` that is analogous to `String`, not the slice of it.

An `str` is a string literal, basically a pre-allocated text:

```rust
"Hello World"
```

This text has to be stored somewhere, so it is stored in the data section of the executable file along with the program’s machine code, as sequence of bytes ([u8]).

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│  H  │  e  │  l  │  l  │  o  │     │  W  │  o  │  r  │  l  │  d  │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│  72 │ 101 │ 108 │ 108 │ 111 │  32 │  87 │ 111 │ 114 │ 108 │ 100 │
└─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Since text can be of any length, they are dynamically-sized.

Now that we stored the text, we need a way to access it and that is where the slice comes in.

A [slice](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/slice.html),`[T]`, is a view into a block of memory. Whether mutable or not, a slice always borrows and that is why it is always behind a [pointer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/pointer.html), `&`.

Lets explain the meaning of being dynamically sized.

Some programming languages, like C, appends a zero byte (`\0`) at the end of its strings and keeps a record of the starting address. To determine a string's length, program has to walk through the raw bytes from starting position until finding this zero byte.

However Rust takes a different approach: It uses a slice. A slice stores the address where a `str` starts and how many byte it takes. It is better than appending zero byte because calculation is done in advance during compilation.

The text size can be known in advance but still changes with the underlying data which makes it dynamically sized.

If we go back to "Hello World" expression, it returns a fat pointer, containing both the address of the actual data and its length. This pointer will be our handle to the actual data and it will also be stored in our program. Now data is behind a pointer and the compiler knows its size at compile time.

Since text is stored in the source code, it will be valid for the entire lifetime of the running program, hence will have the `static` lifetime.

So, return value of "Hello Word" expression should reflect these two characteristics, and it does:

```rust
let s: &'static str = "Hello World";
```

You may ask why its type is written as `str` but not as `[u8]`, it is because data is always guaranteed to be a valid UTF-8 sequence. Not all UTF-8 characters are single byte, some take 4 bytes. So [u8] would be inaccurate.

If you disassemble a compiled Rust program and inspect the executable file, you will see multiple `str`s are stored adjacent to each other in the data section without any indication where one starts and the other ends.

Compiler takes this one step further: If identical static text is used at multiple locations in the program, Rust compiler will optimize the program by creating a single binary block for all duplicate values.

For example, compiler creates a single continuous binary with the content of "Hello World" for the following code even though we use three different literals with `"Hello World"`:

```rust
let x: &'static str = "Hello World";
let y: &'static str = "Hello World";
let z: &'static str = "Hello World";
```

`String`, on the other hand, is a specialized type that stores its value as vector of u8. Take a look at how `String` type is defined in the source code:

```rust
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Being vector means it is heap allocated and resizable like any other vector value.

However, if you look carefully you will see `vec` field is kept private. Being private means, we can not create a String instance directly but through provided methods. Why it is kept private is because not all stream of bytes produce a valid utf-8 characters and direct interaction with the underlying bytes may corrupt the data. Through this controlled access compiler enforces data is valid and remains valid.

The word specialized in the type definition refers to this feature, feature of not permitting arbitrary access but enforcing certain checks on the data through controlled access in order to provide certain guarantees. Other than that, it is just a vector.

In summary, a `String` is a resizable buffer holding UTF-8 text. This buffer is allocated on the heap, so it can grow as needed or requested. We can fill this buffer or can change its content anyway we see fit.

There are several methods defined on String type to create String instance, new is one of them:

```rust
pub const fn new() -> String {
  String { vec: Vec::new() }
}
```

We can use it to create a valid String.

```rust
let s = String::new();
println("{}", s);
```

Unfortunately it does not accept input parameter. So result will be valid but an empty string but it will grow like any other vector when capacity is not enough to hold the assigned value. But application performance will take a hit, as growing requires re-allocation.

We can fill the underlying vector with initial values from different sources:

**From a string literal**

```rust
let a = "Hello World";
let s = String::from(a);
```

Please note that an `str` is still created and its content is copied to the heap allocated vector via `String.from`. If we check the executable binary we will see raw bytes in data section with the content "Hello World". This is very important detail some people miss.

**From raw parts**

```rust
let ptr = s.as_mut_ptr();
let len = s.len();
let capacity = s.capacity();

let s = String::from_raw_parts(ptr, len, capacity);
```

**From a character**

```rust
let ch = 'c';
let s = ch.to_string();
```

**From vector of bytes**

```rust
let hello_world = vec![72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100];
// We know it is valid sequence, so we can use unwrap
let hello_world = String::from_utf8(hello_world).unwrap();
println!("{}", hello_world); // Hello World
```

Here we have another important detail. A vector might have any value, there is no guarantee its content will be a valid UTF-8, so Rust forces us to take this into consideration by returning a `Result<String, FromUtf8Error>` rather than a `String`.

**From input buffer**

```rust
use std::io::{self, Read};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut handle = stdin.lock();

    handle.read_to_string(&mut buffer)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

**Or from any other type that implements `ToString` trait**

Since `String` is a vector under the hood, it will exhibit some vector characteristics:

- a pointer: The pointer points to an internal buffer that stores the data.
- length: The length is the number of bytes currently stored in the buffer.
- capacity: The capacity is the size of the buffer in bytes. So, the length will always be less than or equal to the capacity.

And it delegates some properties and methods to vectors:

```rust
pub fn capacity(&self) -> usize {
  self.vec.capacity()
}
```

Most of the examples uses `String::from`, which makes people get confused thinking why create String from another string.

It is a long read, hope it helps.

Comment: TL;GR => too long but great read, thanks.  I feel like I understand more about strings in rust.  I hope I actually do!

Comment: @snnsnn Thanks for this informative answer. I am an experienced frontend dev. Now, trying to learn rust, but don't know of any good resources. Can you please help me by providing some resources to learn rust. Even, I do not have any background in C/C++. So, I would like to understand hardware level concepts as well.

Comment: @Vishal What do you mean by not knowing any good resource? You could not find any or you did not find them helpful enough because even a simple search returns many resources. If you like the text, it was a part of the book I was writing, I've completed about 8 chapters but did not have time to finish.

Comment: @snnsnn I mean, I found many resources, but none of the resources goes in deep to the hardware level and the resources that takes me deeper are assuming that I already have some level of knowledge in rust. So, I am a bit confused on which path to go. So, I was requesting you to share any good resources if you have. I like the text that you shared, very eager to buy your book when it is available, till then I will keep learning from resources that I find.

Answer (score 73):

[`str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), only used as `&str`, is a string slice, a reference to a UTF-8 byte array.

[`String`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) is what used to be `~str`, a growable, owned UTF-8 byte array.

Comment: Technically, what used to be `~str` is now `Box<str>`

Comment: @jv110: no, because `~str` was growable while `Box<str>` is not growable. (That `~str` and `~[T]` were magically growable, unlike any other `~`-object, was exactly why `String` and `Vec<T>` were introduced, so that the rules were all straightforward and consistent.)

Comment: I also enjoyed [your blog post](https://chrismorgan.info/blog/rust-fizzbuzz/), "Two types of strings? What is this?" In particular: "`String` is an *owned* type... it has exclusive ownership of the contents of the string; and when it passes out of scope, the memory for the contents of the string will be freed immediately. For this reason, any substring can’t be of the type `String`... [otherwise]... when one passed out of scope, the other would become invalid... And so instead it is that slices (substrings) use a type which is a reference to the contents that something else owns—`​&str`..."

Answer (score 71):

They are actually completely different. First off, a `str` is nothing but a type level thing; it can only be reasoned about at the type level because it's a so-called dynamically-sized type (DST). The size the `str` takes up cannot be known at compile time and depends on runtime information — it cannot be stored in a variable because the compiler needs to know at compile time what the size of each variable is. A `str` is conceptually just a row of `u8` bytes with the guarantee that it forms valid UTF-8. How large is the row? No one knows until runtime hence it can't be stored in a variable.

The interesting thing is that a `&str` or any other pointer to a `str` like `Box<str>` *does* exist at runtime. This is a so-called "fat pointer"; it's a pointer with extra information (in this case the size of the thing it's pointing at) so it's twice as large. In fact, a `&str` is quite close to a `String` (but not to a `&String`). A `&str` is two words; one pointer to a the first byte of a `str` and another number that describes how many bytes long the the `str` is.

Contrary to what is said, a `str` does not need to be immutable. If you can get a `&mut str` as an exclusive pointer to the `str`, you can mutate it and all the safe functions that mutate it guarantee that the UTF-8 constraint is upheld because if that is violated then we have undefined behaviour as the library assumes this constraint is true and does not check for it.

So what is a `String`? That's *three* words; two are the same as for `&str` but it adds a third word which is the capacity of the `str` buffer on the heap, always on the heap (a `str` is not necessarily on the heap) it manages before it's filled and has to re-allocate. the `String` basically *owns* a `str` as they say; it controls it and can resize it and reallocate it when it sees fit. So a `String` is as said closer to a `&str` than to a `str`.

Another thing is a `Box<str>`; this also owns a `str` and its runtime representation is the same as a `&str` but it also owns the `str` unlike the `&str` but it cannot resize it because it does not know its capacity so basically a `Box<str>` can be seen as a fixed-length `String` that cannot be resized (you can always convert it into a `String` if you want to resize it).

A very similar relationship exists between `[T]` and `Vec<T>` except there is no UTF-8 constraint and it can hold any type whose size is not dynamic.

The use of `str` on the type level is mostly to create generic abstractions with `&str`; it exists on the type level to be able to conveniently write traits. In theory `str` as a type thing didn't need to exist and only `&str` but that would mean a lot of extra code would have to be written that can now be generic.

`&str` is super useful to be able to to have multiple different substrings of a `String` without having to copy; as said a `String` *owns* the `str` on the heap it manages and if you could only create a substring of a `String` with a new `String` it would have to be copied because everything in Rust can only have one single owner to deal with memory safety. So for instance you can slice a string:

```
let string: String   = "a string".to_string();
let substring1: &str = &string[1..3];
let substring2: &str = &string[2..4];
```

We have two different substring `str`s of the same string. `string` is the one that owns the actual full `str` buffer on the heap and the `&str` substrings are just fat pointers to that buffer on the heap.

Comment: "it cannot be stored in a variable because the compiler needs to know at compile time what the size of each variable is" > Can you explain why can't the compilier produce a binary code which uses run-time information about a string length, please? Is it kind of Rust design constraint?

Comment: @Mergasov It could, but this would be extremely inefficient performance wise, and would completely alter the function calling convention which relies upon this information being known. That the size of a function call stack, and the location of each variable thereon is known at compile time, is very important to producing efficient programs and is the reason why the stack is orders of magnitude faster than the heap. It's far easier in that case to simply put it on the heap behind a pointer; it would essentially be turning the stack into a second heap.

Answer (score 37):

### Rust `&str` and `String`

---

**`String`:**

- Rust's **owned String type**, the string itself lives on the heap and therefore is mutable and can alter its size and contents.
- Because String is owned when the variables which owns the string goes out of scope the memory on the heap will be freed.
- Variables of type `String` are fat pointers (pointer + associated metadata)
- The fat pointer is 3 * 8 bytes (wordsize) long and consists of the following 3 elements:

  - Pointer to actual data on the heap, it points to the first character
  - Length of the string (# of characters)
  - Capacity of the string on the heap

**`&str`:**

- Rust's **non-owned String type**, it's immutable by default. The string itself lives somewhere else in memory usually on the heap or in `'static` memory.
- Because String is non-owned when `&str` variables go out of scope the memory of the string will not be freed.
- Variables of type `&str` are fat pointers (pointer + associated metadata)
- The fat pointer is 2 * 8 bytes (wordsize) long and consists of the following 2 elements:

  - Pointer to actual data on the heap, it points to the first character
  - Length of the string (# of characters)

**Example:**

```
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    // on 64 bit architecture:
    println!("{}", mem::size_of::<&str>()); // 16
    println!("{}", mem::size_of::<String>()); // 24

    let string1: &'static str = "abc";
    // string will point to 'static memory which lives throughout the whole program

    let ptr = string1.as_ptr();
    let len = string1.len();

    println!("{}, {}", unsafe { *ptr as char }, len); // a, 3
    // len is 3 characters long so 3
    // pointer to the first character points to letter a

    {
        let mut string2: String = "def".to_string();

        let ptr = string2.as_ptr();
        let len = string2.len();
        let capacity = string2.capacity();
        println!("{}, {}, {}", unsafe { *ptr as char }, len, capacity); // d, 3, 3
        // pointer to the first character points to letter d
        // len is 3 characters long so 3
        // string has now 3 bytes of space on the heap

        string2.push_str("ghijk"); // we can mutate String type, capacity and length will also change
        println!("{}, {}", string2, string2.capacity()); // defghijk, 8

    } // memory of string2 on the heap will be freed here because owner goes out of scope

}
```

Answer (score 19):

`std::String` is simply a vector of `u8`. You can find its definition in [source code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/79d8a0fcefa5134db2a94739b1d18daa01fc6e9f/src/liballoc/string.rs) . It's heap-allocated and growable.

```
#[derive(PartialOrd, Eq, Ord)]
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

`str` is a primitive type, also called **string slice**. A string slice has fixed size. A literal string like `let test = "hello world"` has `&'static str` type. `test` is a reference to this statically allocated string. 
`&str` cannot be modified, for example,

```
let mut word = "hello world";
word[0] = 's';
word.push('\n');
```

`str` does have mutable slice `&mut str`, for example:
`pub fn split_at_mut(&mut self, mid: usize) -> (&mut str, &mut str)`

```
let mut s = "Per Martin-Löf".to_string();
{
    let (first, last) = s.split_at_mut(3);
    first.make_ascii_uppercase();
    assert_eq!("PER", first);
    assert_eq!(" Martin-Löf", last);
}
assert_eq!("PER Martin-Löf", s);
```

But a small change to UTF-8 can change its byte length, and a slice cannot reallocate its referent.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for a `&mut str` that did not rely on a `String`, that is, without `to_string()`, because why bother with str if you have String already. This works: `let mut s: Box<str> = "Per Martin-Löf".into(); let (first, last) = s.split_at_mut(3); first.make_ascii_uppercase(); assert_eq!("PER Martin-Löf", &*s);`

Comment: The opening sentence makes `String` sound redundant with `Vec<u8>`. The difference between the two is that a `String` always contains valid UTF-8 encoded text while a `Vec<u8>` can hold any sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 13):

In easy words, `String` is datatype stored on heap (just like `Vec`), and you have access to that location.

`&str` is a slice type. That means it is just reference to an already present `String` somewhere in the heap.

`&str` doesn't do any allocation at runtime. So, for memory reasons, you can use `&str` over `String`. But, keep in mind that when using `&str` you might have to deal with explicit lifetimes.

---

Comment: *somewhere in heap* — that is not completely accurate.

Comment: What I meant was that `str` is `view` of already present `String` in heap.

Comment: I understand that's what you meant, and I'm saying that isn't completely accurate. The "heap" isn't a required part of the statement.

Answer (score 10):

> In these 3 different types
>
> ```
> let noodles = "noodles".to_string();
> let oodles = &noodles[1..];
> let poodles = "ಠ_ಠ"; // this is string literal
> ```
>
> - A String has a resizable buffer holding UTF-8 text. The buffer is allocated on the heap, so it can resize its buffer as needed or
>   requested. In the example, "noodles" is a String that owns an
>   eight-byte buffer, of which seven are in use. You can think of a
>   String as a Vec that is guaranteed to hold well-formed UTF-8; in
>   fact, this is how `String` is implemented.
> - A `&str` is a reference to a run of UTF-8 text owned by someone else: it “borrows” the text. In the example, oodles is a &str
>   referring to the last six bytes of the text belonging to "noodles", so
>   it represents the text “oodles.” Like other slice references, a `&str`
>   is a `fat pointer`, containing both the address of the actual data and
>   its length. You can think of a `&str` as being nothing more than a
>   &[u8] that is guaranteed to hold well-formed UTF-8.
> - A `string literal` is a `&str` that refers to preallocated text, typically stored in read-only memory along with the program’s machine
>   code. In the preceding example, poodles is a string literal, pointing
>   to seven bytes that are created when the program begins execution and
>   that last until it exits.
>
> This is how they are stored in memory

[image]

[Reference:Programming Rust,by Jim Blandy, Jason Orendorff, Leonora F . S. Tindall](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust-2nd/9781492052586/)

Answer (score 9):

## Some Usages

example_1.rs

```
fn main(){
  let hello = String::("hello");
  let any_char = hello[0];//error
}
```

example_2.rs

```
fn main(){
  let hello = String::("hello");
  for c in hello.chars() {
    println!("{}",c);
  }
}
```

example_3.rs

```
fn main(){
  let hello = String::("String are cool");
  let any_char = &hello[5..6]; // = let any_char: &str = &hello[5..6];
  println!("{:?}",any_char);
}
```

`Shadowing`

```
fn main() {
  let s: &str = "hello"; // &str
  let s: String = s.to_uppercase(); // String
  println!("{}", s) // HELLO
}
```

`function`

```
fn say_hello(to_whom: &str) { //type coercion
     println!("Hey {}!", to_whom) 
 }


fn main(){
  let string_slice: &'static str = "you";
  let string: String = string_slice.into(); // &str => String
  say_hello(string_slice);
  say_hello(&string);// &String
 }
```

`Concat`

```
 // String is at heap, and can be increase or decrease in its size
// The size of &str is fixed.
fn main(){
  let a = "Foo";
  let b = "Bar";
  let c = a + b; //error
  // let c = a.to_string + b;
}
```

Note that `String` and `&str` are different types and for 99% of the time, you only should care about `&str`.

Answer (score 7):

`String` is an Object.

`&str` is a pointer at a part of object.

[image]

Comment: When people say "`&str` is like a *view* (slice) of data", it can sometimes sound confusing; This graphic shows it very well. The only thing that this answer doesn't really help with is that `String` is owned and mutable, whereas `&str` is immutable and non-owned.

Answer (score 6):

For C# and Java people:

- Rust' `String` === `StringBuilder`
- Rust's `&str`  === (immutable) string

I like to think of a `&str` as a view on a string, like an interned string in Java / C# where you can't change it, only create a new one.

Comment: The biggest difference between Java/C# strings and Rust strings is that Rust guarentees the string to be correct unicode, as such getting the third charactor in a string requires more thought than just "abc"[2]. (Given we live in a multi-lingual world, this is a good thing.)

Comment: [This is incorrect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_mut_str). The topic of mutability is already addressed in the top-voted answer; please read it to learn more.

Comment: &mut str is pretty uncommon and is different from &str.

Answer (score 5):

In Rust, str is a primitive type that represents a sequence of Unicode scalar values, also known as a string slice. This means that it is a read-only view into a string, and it does not own the memory that it points to. On the other hand, String is a growable, mutable, owned string type. This means that when you create a String, it will allocate memory on the heap to store the contents of the string, and it will deallocate this memory when the String goes out of scope. Because String is growable and mutable, you can change the contents of a String after you have created it.

In general, str is used when you want to refer to a string slice that is stored in another data structure, such as a String. String is used when you want to create and own a string value.

Answer (score 0):

**String:**

- A String is a dynamic, heap-allocated, grow-able sequence of
  characters.
- Used for storing and manipulating text data that can change in size.
- Represents owned string data.

*Example:*

```
let s: String = String::from("Hello");
println!("{}", s); 
// Output: Hello
```

**&str (String Slice):**

- A &str is an immutable reference to a sequence of characters (a
  slice) stored in memory.
- Used for working with string data without taking ownership.
- Can be used with string literals or borrow from String.

*Example:*

```
fn print_length(s: &str) {
    println!("Length: {}", s.len());
}

let greeting = "Hello";
print_length(greeting); 
// Output: Length: 5
```

Keep in mind that String and &str are related, but they serve different purposes and have different ownership characteristics in Rust.

Answer (score -10):

Here is a quick and easy explanation.

`String` - A growable, ownable heap-allocated data structure. It can be coerced to a `&str`.

`str` - is (now, as Rust evolves) mutable, fixed-length string that lives on the heap or in the binary. You can only interact with `str` as a borrowed type via a string slice view, such as `&str`.

Usage considerations:

Prefer `String` if you want to own or mutate a string - such as passing the string to another thread, etc.

Prefer `&str` if you want to have a read-only view of a string.

Comment: [This is incorrect](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_mut_str). The topic of mutability is already addressed in the top-voted answer; please read it to learn more.

Comment: @Shepmaster You are equivocating `&str` and `&mut str` in all the replies. Two different things.