# Collect into owned vec of owned strings in rust

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I am trying to collect into an vec of strings in rust using the following:

```
let fields : ~[~str] = row.split_str(",").collect();
```

I get the following error: expected std::iter::FromIterator<&str>, but found std::iter::FromIterator<~str> (str storage differs: expected `&` but found `~`)

I have tried to use type hints but with no success

Comment: What version of Rust are you using?

Comment: The tilde syntax was removed from the language -- replaced by the Box.  If you are not a computer historian, I recommend skipping this question completely.  This one is similar but newer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690352/how-to-return-a-vector-of-strings-in-rust

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`.split_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.10/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.split_str) returns an [iterator over `&str` slices](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.10/std/str/struct.StrSplits.html), that is, it is returning subviews of the `row` data. The borrowed `&str` is not an owned `~str`: to make this work, either collect to a `~[&str]`, or, copy each `&str` into a `~str` before collecting:

```
let first: ~[&str] = row.split_str(",").collect();
let second: ~[~str] = row.split_str(",").map(|s| s.to_owned()).collect();
```

---

FWIW, if you're splitting on a single-character predicate, then [`split`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/0.10/std/str/trait.StrSlice.html#tymethod.split) will be more efficient, (e.g. `row.split(',')` in this case).

Also, I recommend you [upgrade to a more recent version of Rust](http://www.rust-lang.org/install.html), 0.11 was recently released, but the nightlies are the recommended install targets (change the `0.10` to `0.11` or `master` in the above documentation links for the corresponding docs).

With the nightly, the two snippets above would be written as:

```
let first: Vec<&str> = row.split(',').collect();
let second: Vec<String> = row.split(',').map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
```

(Lastly, if you're struggling with the distinction of `&str` vs. `~str` aka `String`, [I wrote up some details a while ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/1256624).)

Comment: Thanks! And yes I am now upgrading and changing my syntax.