# How to convert from &[u8] to Vec<u8>?

Tags: rust

I'm attempting to simply convert a slice to a vector. The following code:

```
let a = &[0u8];
let b: Vec<u8> = a.iter().collect();
```

fails with the following error message:

```
3 |     let b: Vec<u8> = a.iter().collect();
  |                               ^^^^^^^ a collection of type `std::vec::Vec<u8>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&u8`
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `u8` != `&u8`.  Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24689463/collect-into-owned-vec-of-owned-strings-in-rust, but the syntax changed a little bit since then.

Comment: @Stefan What does `u8` have to do with strings?

Comment: let a = &[0u8];
let b: Vec<&u8> = a.iter().collect();
@Roxy , I tried this and it does work for me. If we make the genric as &u8 for b:Vec.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The iterator only returns references to the elements (here `&u8`). To get owned values (here `u8`), you can used `.cloned()`.

```
let a: &[u8] = &[0u8];
let b: Vec<u8> = a.iter().cloned().collect();
```

Answer (score 105):

Collecting into a `Vec` is so common that slices have a method [`to_vec`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) that does exactly this:

```
let b = a.to_vec();
```

You get the same thing as [CodesInChaos's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980272/3650362), but more concisely.

Notice that `to_vec` requires `T: Clone`. To get a `Vec<T>` out of a `&[T]` you have to be able to get an owned `T` out of a non-owning `&T`, which is what `Clone` does.

[Slices also implement `ToOwned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#impl-ToOwned), so you can use `to_owned` instead of `to_vec` if you want to be generic over different types of non-owning container. If your code only works with slices, prefer `to_vec` instead.

Comment: I actually needed to do something more complicated and unfortunately `to_vec` didn't work. The error I get is: `error[E0599]: no method named to_vec found for type std::iter::Take<std::iter::Cycle<std::slice::Iter<'_, u8>>> in the current scope`

Comment: @Roxy That's a different question: "how do I convert an iterator to a `Vec`?" `.collect()` is definitely the right answer to that one.

Answer (score 3):

The clearest way to write this is simply

```
let b = Vec::from(a);
```

which makes it clear you are constructing a `Vec` object (the name of the type is there on the same line) using a `from` style constructor. (Again, the existence of the constructor function call makes this clear.)

Using `to_vec` is almost as clear but I suppose `to_vec` could be a random function in scope to do almost anything, and it doesn't contain the type name `Vec`.

Comment: Well, if it is on slices, it is definitely this `to_vec()`. And if this is somewhen changed to another type, well, if someone creates a method named `to_vec()` that doesn't returns a `Vec`... Well, I suppose this is a _very bad_ design.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I agree that it would be bad design if to_vec would return something else. But that aside, this answer is clear and provides an answer that works for arrays as well as slices. Using the actual Vec type removes any doubt. Looks very elegant to me.

Comment: @GolezTrol The `to_vec()` function is there so that people will use it. This is the most idiomatic solution, otherwise this function wouldn't exist.

Comment: You can say exactly the same for `from`, right? There are two ways to do it. What makes one of them wrong?

Comment: @GolezTrol No, the same argument doesn't apply to `from()`, for a very simple reason: `to_vec()` is an inherent method. It can only be called directly. Therefore, it is _meant_ to be called directly. On the other hand, `from()` (and `to_owned()`) are trait implementations, and are useful whenever something takes `impl Into<Vec>`, even if they are not used directly.

Comment: I used to take the view that `from` was a constructor function. I now take the view it is more of a general conversion function. If viewed as a constructor, it makes little sense to construct a complex type "from" a String. However, as a general conversion function, it does make sense to transmute "from" a String to some more complex type. `to_vec` suggests your type knows how to convert itself into a Vec, which is rarely a sensible thing for a type to do, unless it is strongly coupled with the Vec type itself. (Hence slices can call `to_vec`)

Comment: If you had a `Matrix` type, then it might make sense to have a `to_vec` for example.