# rust - Send data from function argument (from a thread) into mpsc channel

Tags: rust

I'm trying to handle `TcpStream` using threads in a Rust program (a tcp server). I want to keep tracks of currents clients connections in a `HashMap` using an `Arc<Mutex<HashMap>>`.

When a thread is finished, to remove the connection from the HashMap, I thought about using an `uuid`, passed to the function used to handle the stream. Like this it could be send inside a mpsc channel to the main thread and then remove the connection from the `HashMap`.

The code from the main thread :

```rust
let clients_streams = Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new()));

// Server thread. Create channel
let (server_sender, server_receiver) = mpsc::channel();

loop {
    for stream in server_socket.incoming() {
        let clients_streams = Arc::clone(&clients_streams);
        let server_sender = server_sender.clone();
        let mut cs = clients_streams.lock().unwrap();

        match stream {
            Ok(stream) => {
                let mut cs = clients_streams.lock().unwrap();
                let uuid = Uuid::new_v4().to_string();
                cs.insert(uuid.clone(), stream.try_clone());

                thread::spawn(move || {
                    handle_client(stream, server_sender.clone(), uuid.clone());
                })
            }
            Err(err) => thread::spawn(move || {
                println!("Connection failed : {}", err);
            }),
        };
    }
```

The `handle_client` function :

```rust
fn handle_client<'a>(stream: TcpStream, sender: mpsc::Sender<&'a [u8]>, uuid: String) {
    let mut reader = BufReader::new(&stream);
    let mut writer = BufWriter::new(&stream);

    writer.write(b"Hello\n").unwrap();
    writer.flush().unwrap();

    // Read from client
    loop {
        let mut resp = Vec::new();
        let read_bytes = reader.read_until(b'\n', &mut resp);
        match read_bytes {
            Ok(read_bytes) => {
                if read_bytes == 0 {
                    let msg = format!("end of {}", uuid);
                    println!("connection closed by remote");
                    sender.send(msg.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                    break;
                };
            }
            Err(err) => match err.kind() {
                io::ErrorKind::Interrupted => continue,
                _ => break,
            },
        }
    }
}
```

This code doesn't compile, it shows this error but I don't understand how to resolve it. The variable `msg` doesn't live long enough, because of the `uuid` inside of it, but why ? I had to add the lifetime because I'm sending `uuid` inside the channel.

```
 fn handle_client<'a>(stream: TcpStream, sender: mpsc::Sender<&'a [u8]>, uuid: String) {
             -- lifetime `'a` defined here

                sender.send(msg.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                ------------^^^------------
                |           |
                |           borrowed value does not live long enough
                argument requires that `msg` is borrowed for `'a`
                break;
            };
            - `msg` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uuid does not affect msg because format macro creates a clean new String. You are trying to send a &[u8] (this is what as_bytes() return). You need to find a way to remove this reference. (maybe this something like [How to convert from &[u8] to Vec<u8>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980023/how-to-convert-from-u8-to-vecu8)) You can also share references with Rc.

PS: this more a comment than an answer but I can't post answers

Comment: I'm now sending a `Vec<u8>` instead of the `&[u8]` in the channel and now it works. Thanks !