# Can I filter out specific a number from a &[u32] and convert it to a Vec<u32>?

Tags: rust

Given a `&[u32]` I want to filter out the number `0`. This could be any number or any other rule or condition.

Here are a few versions that work, but I feel like this could be done simpler:

```
fn test(factors: &[u32]) {
    let factors1 = factors
        .iter()
        .map(|&x| x as u32)
        .filter(|x| *x != 0)
        .collect::<Vec<u32>>();

    let factors1 = factors
        .iter()
        .map(|&x| x as u32)
        .filter(|&x| x != 0)
        .collect::<Vec<u32>>();

    let factors2 = factors
        .iter()
        .filter(|x| **x != 0)
        .collect::<Vec<&u32>>();

    let factors3 = factors
        .iter()
        .filter(|&&x| x != 0)
        .collect::<Vec<&u32>>();
}
```

I was expecting something simpler like this (which doesn't work):

```
let factors4 = factors.iter().filter(|x| x != 0).collect();
```

Things that would be helpful are:

- Is it possible to clone or convert a `&u32` to `u32`?
- Is there a way to clone a `&[u32]` to `[u32]`?

Comment: "Is there a way to clone a &[u32] to [u32]?" a slice can't be build like this you need a reference somewhere

Comment: @Stargateur **&[u32]** = a reference to a *u32* array? Surely there must be a way to create a new u32 array that has the values (not a reference) to the elements?

Comment: as I said `[u32]` is a slice NOT an array. An array is `[u32; 42]`. Be sure to use exact term. You can construct an array, but not a slice (without the reference), you can construct a reference to a slice but not a slice alone. I give it to you slice and slice can refer to `&[u32]` or `[u32]` but you can construct a `&[u32]` but not a `[u32]`

Comment: You may [construct a `Vec<u32>` using the `to_vec` method on slices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980023/how-to-convert-from-u8-to-vecu8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There’s [`Iterator.copied()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied), at least?

```
let factors4: Vec<u32> = factors
    .iter()
    .copied()
    .filter(|&x| x != 0)
    .collect();
```

Comment: Thanks! **copied** seems like a good choice:  _This is useful when you have an iterator over &T, but you need an iterator over T._

Comment: why do we still have to use the reference symbol in _filter_ `.filter(|&x| x != 0)` ?

Comment: @xx1xx: Because `filter` can’t take ownership of the values in the iterator it’s testing. It still has to pass them through.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`filter_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter_map) to `filter` and `map` in a single step.

```
fn make_vec_of_nonzero(factors: &[u32]) -> Vec<u32> {
    factors
        .iter()
        .filter_map(|&x| if x == 0 { None } else { Some(x) })
        .collect()
}
```