# Copy array and modify one value in Rust

Tags: arrays, rust

I have an struct with a refence to an array of type T:

```rust
pub struct myStruct<'a, T> {
    pub data: &'a [T],
}
```

I want to modify one element of this array and check the result of an operation. for that I am trying to copy the array, modify the value and execute the operation:

```rust
pub fn check_value(&self, data: &T, position: usize) -> bool {
    if position >= self.data.len() {
        return false;
    }
    let array_temp = Box::new(self.data);
    array_temp[position] = *data;

    return mycheck(array_temp);
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
error[E0594]: cannot assign to `array_temp[_]` which is behind a `&` reference
```

I would like to know how to copy the array and modify the value or just modify directly the value in the original array (*data*) and restore the original value later.

Here you have a complete code to compile

```rust
pub struct MyStruct<'a, T> {
    pub data: &'a [T],
}

impl<'a, T> MyStruct<'a, T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    fn mycheck(&self, myarray: &[T]) -> bool {
        if myarray.len() > 0 {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    pub fn check_value(&self, data: &T, position: usize) -> bool {
        if position >= self.data.len() {
            return false;
        }
        let array_temp = Box::new(self.data);
        array_temp[position] = *data;
        return self.mycheck(&array_temp);
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!");
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to convert from &\[u8\] to Vec<u8>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47980023/how-to-convert-from-u8-to-vecu8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have an array (whose length is known), but you have a slice (whose length is not known at compile time). Thus, you must adjust to the dynamic length.

You probably want to use [`self.data.to_vec()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.to_vec) instead of `Box::new(self.data)`.

`to_vec` copies the values into a newly allocated vector having enough capacity.

Comment: I see, the dynamic (run time) arrays (fixed lenght) are someway the "slices" in Rust. Coming from C/C++ this is not a clear conversion.

https://aminb.gitbooks.io/rust-for-c/content/arrays/index.html