# How to return a vector of strings in rust

Tags: string, vector, rust

How can I return a vector of strings by splitting a string that has spaces in between

```
fn line_to_words(line: &str) -> Vec<String> {     
    line.split_whitespace().collect()
}
    
fn main() {
    println!( "{:?}", line_to_words( "string with spaces in between" ) );
}
```

The above code returns this error

```
line.split_whitespace().collect()
  |                           ^^^^^^^ value of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&str>`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::FromIterator<&str>` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>`
```

Comment: It looks lke you changed your question to a different question, and now the answers don't fit the question anymore. Please use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question, rather than editing an old question. I'm rolling back your changes.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to return `Vec<String>` you need to convert the `Iterator<Item=&str>` that you get from `split_whitespace` into an `Iterator<Item=String>`. One way to convert iterator types is using `Iterator::map`.
The function to convert `&str` to `String` is `str::to_string`. Putting this together gives you

```
fn line_to_words(line: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    line.split_whitespace().map(str::to_string).collect()
}
```

Comment: How can I return a result instead of Vec<String>
Ex: Result< Vec<String>, InvalidError> > {
....
....
}

Comment: @rusty Just change the return type of the function, and wrap the return value in `Ok()`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because `split_whitespace` returns a &str. I see two options:

- return a `Vec<&str>`
- convert the result of `split_whitespace` by using `map(|s| s.to_string())`

Comment: How can I return a result instead of Vec<String>
Ex: Result< Vec<String>, InvalidError> > {
....
....
}

Comment: You change the return type, and wrap the result in a `Ok()` [see here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/). Maybe change your question to include this if it's very important.