# Prolonging a 'for' variable's life

Tags: rust

when I compile the below code in Rust 0.12.0, I get the following error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
let _ = match re.captures(a_line.unwrap().as_slice()) {
```

How do I prolong *a_line*'s lifetime so that *c1* can be pushed onto *vect1*?

```
let vect = process_file(filename_ref);
...
fn process_file(filename: &str) -> Vec<&str> {

    let re = regex!(r"^(\w+)\t(\w+)\t(\w+)\t(\w+)\n$");
    let mut vect1 = Vec::new();

    let filepath = Path::new(filename);
    let _ = match File::open(&filepath) {
        Ok(f) => {
            let mut filebuffer = BufferedReader::new(f);
            for a_line in filebuffer.lines() {
                let _ = match re.captures(a_line.unwrap().as_slice()) {
                    Some(c) =>  {
                        let c1 = c.at(1);
                        vect1.push(c1);
                        ...
                    },
                   ...
               };
           } // end for
       },
       Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e)
   };

   return vect1;

}
```

Comment: The lifetime it is speaking of is the result of `a_line.unwrap()` I believe, not `a_line` it self. You might have to do: `let unwrapped = a_line.unwrap(); let_ = match re.captures(unwrapped.as_slice()) {`

Comment: Alas, if you create the 'unwrapped' variable, the compiler says that it does not live long enough.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is, no, you can't just 'extend' the lifetime of a variable like this.

This is a game of connect the types:

- [`.lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/io/trait.Buffer.html#method.lines) returns a [`Lines`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/io/struct.Lines.html) instance, which is an `Iterator<IoResult<String>>`.
- `a_line` is an [`IoResult`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/io/type.IoResult.html)`<String> = Result<String, IoError>`, and so [`.unwrap`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/result/type.Result.html#method.unwrap) returns a `String`
- [`.as_slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/string/struct.String.html#method.as_slice) gives a non-owning view of the string's data which is, via the `'a` lifetime on the references, statically restricted to only be usable while the `String` exists avoiding the problem of dangling references and use-after-free in C++ (for more about `String` vs. `&str`: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/1256624) & [the strings guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/guide-strings.html)).
- [`.captures`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/regex/type.Regex.html#method.captures) takes a `&str` with some lifetime (the `'t`) and tries to return a [`Captures`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/regex/struct.Captures.html) that lasts that long. In this case, the lifetime of the `&str` is the lifetime of the `String` out of `a_line`, and so `c` is a `Captures` storing data that is only valid this long.
- [`.at`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/regex/struct.Captures.html#method.at) returns a `&str` with the `'t` lifetime of the data that the `Captures` is storing, that is, the returned `&str` is only guaranteed to last as long as the original `&str` fed into `captures` (which can't be longer than how long the original `String` exists, since that's managing the text in memory)

Hence, `c1` only lasts for as long as the `String` from `a_line`, and that `String` is scoped inside the loop, that is, each time you step through the loop, you get a new `String` which is deallocated at the end. If the compiler let it escape by allowing it to be placed in `vect1`, the code would be prone to use-after-free/dangling reference memory safety bugs as the `String` each `&str` points into is freed at the end of each iteration (e.g. all the `&str`s in `vect1` on the `return vect1` line would be pointing to garbage).

To fix this, you need to cut the memory dependency: currently the `&str`s are not in control of their own memory, and thus are dependent on the "parent" `String`s being placed correctly. Instead, you could give the vector contents control of its own destiny (well, memory), by making them fully-fledged `String`s, e.g. `vect1.push(c1.to_string())`. This will make `vect1` a `Vec<String>`, and then there is no longer a connection between those values and the `a_line` value inside the loop. That variable can then be freed/mangled/munged as much as it likes without affecting the contents of `vect1`.