# How to create a Rust struct with string members?

Tags: string, rust

I want the members to be owned by the struct. I'm looking for the correct declaration of a struct and instantiation examples. I wasn't able to find an example.

Comment: Use `String` and be aware that creating a `String` from `&str` via `.to_string()` involves a heap allocation + copying the whole string.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

If the string has to be owned by the struct, then you should use `String`. Alternatively, you could use an `&str` with a static lifetime (i.e., the lifetime of the program). For example:

```
struct Foo {
    bar: String,
    baz: &'static str,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        bar: "bar".to_string(),
        baz: "baz",
    };
    println!("{}, {}", foo.bar, foo.baz);
}
```

If the lifetime of the string is unknown, then you can parameterize `Foo` with a lifetime:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    baz: &'a str,
}
```

See also:

- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/155423)

If you're not sure whether the string will be owned or not (useful for avoiding allocations), then you can use [`borrow::Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

struct Foo<'a> {
    baz: Cow<'a, str>,
}

fn main() {
    let foo1 = Foo {
        baz: Cow::Borrowed("baz"),
    };
    let foo2 = Foo {
        baz: Cow::Owned("baz".to_string()),
    };
    println!("{}, {}", foo1.baz, foo2.baz);
}
```

Note that the `Cow` type is parameterized over a lifetime. The lifetime refers to the lifetime of the *borrowed* string (i.e., when it is a `Borrowed`). If you have a `Cow`, then you can use `borrow` and get a `&'a str`, with which you can do normal string operations without worrying about whether to allocate a new string or not. Typically, explicit calling of `borrow` isn't required because of deref coercions. Namely, `Cow` values will dereference to their borrowed form automatically, so `&*val` where `val` has type `Cow<'a, str>` will produce a `&str`.

Comment: Uhhh, thank you for the full answer. I need to think about the lifetime parametrization another day :)

Comment: if I have a structure that includes the Copy attribute (eg #[derive(Clone, Copy)], then String doesn't compile. What is the best solution?

Comment: Don't use String? That might seem like a curt answer, but the way you asked your question doesn't leave me much choice. I suspect you are hitting am instance of the XY problem. I'd recommend asking a new question detailing the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: The documentation states that `String` is mutable. If I have a struct with, say, a `name` field that should be immutable, should I still use `String` instead of `str`?

Comment: I don't see how that's relevant to this question. I'd suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: If I know I'm never going to want to mutate the string, is there a reason to use `String` over `Box<str>`?

Comment: I don't believe so. If you don't need mutation but want ownership, `Box<str>` seems like the way to go.