# Immutable Strings and Cloning

Tags: memory-management, rust, ownership, ownership-semantics

I have the mindset keeping my `String`s immutable, a single source of truth.
As I take the same mindset into Rust, I find I have to do a lot of cloning.
Since the `String`s do not change, all the cloning is unnecessary.
Below there is an example of this and [link to the relevant playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44d7b3b93af8547d94b00abf71b20a8c).

Borrowing does not seem like an option as I would have to deal with references and their lifetimes. My next thought is to use something like `Rc` or `Cow` struct.  But wrapping all the `String`s with something like `Rc` feels unnatural. In my limited experience of Rust, I have never seen any exposed ownership/memory management structs, that is `Rc` and `Cow`. I am curious how a more experience Rust developer would handle such a problem.

Is it actually natural in Rust to expose ownership/memory management structs like `Rc` and `Cow`? Should I be using slices?

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Check {
    Known(String),
    Duplicate(String),
    Missing(String),
    Unknown(String)
}

fn main() {
    let known_values: HashSet<_> = [
        "a".to_string(),
        "b".to_string(),
        "c".to_string()]
            .iter().cloned().collect();

    let provided_values = vec![
        "a".to_string(),
        "b".to_string(),
        "z".to_string(),
        "b".to_string()
    ];

    let mut found = HashSet::new();

    let mut check_values: Vec<_> = provided_values.iter().cloned()
        .map(|v| {
            if known_values.contains(&v) {
                if found.contains(&v) {
                    Check::Duplicate(v)
                } else {
                    found.insert(v.clone());
                    Check::Known(v)
                }
            } else {
                Check::Unknown(v)
            }
        }).collect();

    let missing = known_values.difference(&found);

    check_values = missing
        .cloned()
        .fold(check_values, |mut cv, m| {
            cv.push(Check::Missing(m));
            cv
        });

    println!("check_values: {:#?}", check_values);
}
```

Comment: *In my limited experience of Rust, I have never seen any exposed memory management structs* -- `String` and `Vec` manage their own memory, just like `Rc` does.

Comment: In languages like Java strings are accessed by reference and the same objects are shared by many pieces of code. Rust doesn't work that way. Ownership is explicit. You'd have to deliberately pass a `&mut` reference or similar to have some other code mutate a string you own. I think you're carrying over habits from another language that don't apply to Rust.

Comment: @trentcl This isn't the point of my question. Yes, I know `String` and `Vec` mange their own memory, but they still succumb to ownership rules. I can't pass a `String` or `Vec` around without moving or borrowing. This is why I focused on `Rc` and `Cow` in my question.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I work in a lot of languages, so it is very likely that I am carrying over habits from another language.

Comment: The impression that I'm getting is to encapsulate ownership/memory mangement.

Comment: It seemed to me, from the phrasing of the part I quoted, that you weren't aware that `String` and `Vec` are also "memory management structs". Yes, if you want a pointer with shared ownership semantics, you probably want something like `Rc<str>` or `Arc<str>`.

Comment: For your example the lifetimes of all the strings are long enough that you can just use &str everywhere. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=795d60b705dab4561a20030be545ccca. I tend to use &str if I can, and String only if I really need independent ownership of a value, or to construct a new value.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson You are right and thanks for the advice. But this being example code, it is best not to read too much into it. It is a simplified version of the real thing and I kept it close as possible by using similar types.

Answer (score 0):

From the discussion in the comments of my question, all the cloning of immutable `String`s in the example is correct. The cloning is necessary due to Rust handling memory via ownership rather than a reference in other languages.

At best, without using `Rc`, I can see some reduction in the cloning by using move semantics on `provided_values`.

**Update**: Some interesting reading

- https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/5xjl95/rc_or_cloning/
- https://medium.com/swlh/ownership-managing-memory-in-rust-ce7bf3f5c9d5
- [How to create a Rust struct with string members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754863/how-to-create-a-rust-struct-with-string-members)

`Cow` would not work in my example as it involves a borrowing of a reference. `Rc` would be what I would have to use. In my example everything has to be converted to `Rc` but I can see the potential that this could all be hidden away through encapsulation.

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Check {
    Known(Rc<String>),
    Duplicate(Rc<String>),
    Missing(Rc<String>),
    Unknown(Rc<String>)
}

fn main() {
    let known_values: HashSet<_> = [
        Rc::new("a".to_string()),
        Rc::new("b".to_string()),
        Rc::new("c".to_string())]
            .iter().cloned().collect();

    let provided_values = vec![
        Rc::new("a".to_string()),
        Rc::new("b".to_string()),
        Rc::new("z".to_string()),
        Rc::new("b".to_string())
    ];

    let mut found = HashSet::new();

    let mut check_values: Vec<_> = provided_values.iter().cloned()
        .map(|v| {
            if known_values.contains(&v) {
                if found.contains(&v) {
                    Check::Duplicate(v)
                } else {
                    found.insert(v.clone());
                    Check::Known(v)
                }
            } else {
                Check::Unknown(v)
            }
        }).collect();

    let missing = known_values.difference(&found);

    check_values = missing
        .cloned()
        .fold(check_values, |mut cv, m| {
            cv.push(Check::Missing(m));
            cv
        });

    println!("check_values: {:#?}", check_values);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c01ac75ac4833485bc39f8163c51241d)

Comment: You might also want to try `Rc<str>` instead of `Rc<String>` - since your strings are anyway immutable, this might work too, with one less layer of indirection.