# What is the best way to avoid immutable references in Rust when a mutable one is needed?

Tags: rust

I'm having the problem shown in the sample case here:

```rust
struct Deck<'a> {
    cards: Vec<&'a str>
}
impl Deck<'_> {
    fn top_in_deck(&self) -> &str {
        self.cards[0]
    }
    fn remove_top_in_deck_if_is_card(&mut self, card: &str) {
        if self.cards[0] == card {
            self.cards.remove(0);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut deck = Deck { cards: vec!["9-H", "K-D"] };
    let top_card = deck.top_in_deck();
    deck.remove_top_in_deck_if_is_card(top_card);
}
```

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `deck` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:5
   |
17 |     let top_card = deck.top_in_deck();
   |                    ------------------ immutable borrow occurs here
18 |     deck.remove_top_in_deck_if_is_card(top_card);
   |     ^^^^^-----------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |    |
   |     |    immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I do understand the problem, I get a read-only reference from `top_in_deck`, so then I can't call `remove_top_in_deck_if_is_card` which needs a mutable reference. But I'm not sure what would be the best way to make something like this work. I tried cloning the string returned by `top_in_deck`, thinking that maybe the compiler would understand that the return of the function is not a reference to the struct, but it didn't work. Does anyone know what to do in a case like this?

Comment: Cloning a `&str` is meaningless. If you want an owned `String`, you need to call `.to_owned()` or `.to_string()` on it. This is one way to resolve the problem. Another is to return the index of the card instead of its content.

Comment: without context it's hard to answer, you can look at entry api of hashmap std that a very interesting way to solve such problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple solutions:

#### 1. Simple fix: use `&'static str`.

The type of`"9-H"` is actually `&'static str`. Use that type directly instead of `&'a str`.

[Smartass mode on:] Your code casts `Vec<&'static str>` into `Vec<&'a str>` and it's possible because `Vec` is covariant on the lifetime of its type parameter. Sounds complicated? Yes it is, avoid it if you can, this solution comes with its own can of worms.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=feb9e83711d0da544dba882b79a25f47)

#### 2. Preferred design: don't store borrowed references on the heap.

Use value types to represent your cards. Anything that implements `Copy` will work better on the long term because lifetimes need additional attention and references have lifetimes. If you use references, your `Deck` won't own the cards it stores.

There are multiple simple ways: `type Card = i32`, or an `enum Card`, or maybe a custom `struct` with simple fields.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I made the example with static strings and cards to make it simpler, but what I'd store in the vector in practice would be arbitrary strings. I guess 2 solves and answers my problem, I guess I should rather use `String` in the struct instead of `&str`. Thanks a lot for the hint, I think your answer is correct for my question, but this is the exact answer I needed for the actual problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25754863/how-to-create-a-rust-struct-with-string-members