# How would I create and use a string to string Hashmap in Rust?

Tags: rust

How would I idiomatically create a string to string hashmap in rust. The following works, but is it the right way to do it? is there a different kind of string I should be using?

```
use std::collections::hashmap::HashMap;
//use std::str;
fn main() {
        let mut mymap = HashMap::new();
        mymap.insert("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string());
        println!("{0}", mymap["foo".to_string()]);
}
```

Comment: Does it need to be owned strings? Can you do it with `&'static str` (string literals), especially for the keys?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Assuming you would like the flexibility of `String`, `HashMap<String, String>` is correct. The other choice is `&str`, but that imposes significant restrictions on how the `HashMap` can be used/where it can be passed around; but if it it works, changing one or both parameter to `&str` will be more efficient. This choice should be dictated by what sort of ownership semantics you need, and how dynamic the strings are, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/1256624) and [the strings guide](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/guide-strings.html) for more.

BTW, searching a `HashMap<String, ...>` with a `String` can be expensive: if you don't already have one, it requires allocating a new `String`. We have a work around in the form of [`find_equiv`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.find_equiv), which allows you to pass a string literal (and, more generally, any `&str`) without allocating a new `String`:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
fn main() {
    let mut mymap = HashMap::new();
    mymap.insert("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string());
    println!("{}", mymap.find_equiv(&"foo"));
    println!("{}", mymap.find_equiv(&"not there"));
}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20mymap%20%3D%20HashMap%3A%3Anew%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20mymap.insert%28%22foo%22.to_string%28%29%2C%20%22bar%22.to_string%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20mymap.find_equiv%28%26%22foo%22%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20mymap.find_equiv%28%26%22not%20there%22%29%29%3B%0A%7D) (note I've left the `Option` in the return value, one could call `.unwrap()` or handle a missing key properly).

Another slightly different option (more general in some circumstances, less in others), is the [`std::string::as_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/string/fn.as_string.html) function, which allows viewing the data in `&str` as if it were a `&String`, without allocating (as [the name suggests](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/wiki/Doc-detailed-release-notes#cast-naming-conventions)). It returns an object that can be dereferenced to a `String`, e.g.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::string;

fn main() {
    let mut mymap = HashMap::new();
    mymap.insert("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string());
    println!("{}", mymap[*string::as_string("foo")]);
}
```

[playpen](http://play.rust-lang.org/?run=1&code=use%20std%3A%3Acollections%3A%3AHashMap%3B%0Ause%20std%3A%3Astring%3B%0A%0Afn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20mymap%20%3D%20HashMap%3A%3Anew%28%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20mymap.insert%28%22foo%22.to_string%28%29%2C%20%22bar%22.to_string%28%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20mymap%5B*string%3A%3Aas_string%28%22foo%22%29%5D%29%3B%0A%7D)

(There is a similar [`std::vec::as_vec`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/vec/fn.as_vec.html).)

Comment: Could [`MaybeOwned`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/enum.MaybeOwned.html) allow some flexibility here? It seems it could be used as key?

Comment: @MatthieuM that is another approach, yeah.

Comment: I take it `find_equiv()` is no longer necessary? Your Playpen example doesn't compile anymore, and I don't see a `find_equiv` method on `HashMap`.

Comment: `find_equiv()` has been removed in favor of the [`Borrow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) trait. Conversion between `&str` and `&String` is done automatically now when using [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html) get/contains/remove methods. Working playpen [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a3d3d81aa5917cad982bb8e0b5ff0ed1&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

Comment: What exactly are the "significant restrictions" that using `&str` would place on the HashMap?

Comment: @Chad: [Difficulty using any `str` with non-`'static` lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77447356/364696). If it's keyed entirely with literal str with `'static` lifetime, it's fine. If it's deriving those keys from existing `String`s with more limited lifetimes, you need to ensure they stay alive at least as long as the `HashMap`, which is a royal pain.

Answer (score 14):

Writing this answer for future readers. [huon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324805/14020202) is correct at the time but [`*_equiv` methods were purged](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/12135) some time ago.

The [HashMap documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#examples) provides an example on using String-String hashmaps, where `&str` can be used.

The following code will work just fine. No new `String` allocation necessary:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let mut mymap = HashMap::new();
    mymap.insert("foo".to_string(), "bar".to_string());
    println!("{0}", mymap["foo"]);
    println!("{0}", mymap.get("foo").unwrap());
}
```