# How would using type &str for the key in a HashMap restrict how the HashMap can be used?

Tags: rust

I'm reading the Rust book, and [section 8.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch08-03-hash-maps.html) introduces the HashMap collection. The example creates a map of team names to scores, defined as a `HashMap<String,i32>`.

From what I've learned about `String` and `&str`, it seems that a `HashMap<&str,i32>` would be more efficient, since team names are hardcoded literal strings and won't be changing.

Trying to understand the advantage of using `String`, I Googled and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26324805/1538270) which agreed that `&str` is more efficient, but noted that using `&str`

> imposes significant restrictions on how the HashMap can be used/where it can be passed around

What exactly are these "significant restrictions" if `&str` is used?

(The above answer pointed to a couple of links for more info; I followed those and they explained a lot about strings, but I still don't see exactly how using `&str` would place restrictions on a HashMap).

I've read [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)) and it's very useful, but it still doesn't make clear to me what restrictions using `&str` would place on a HashMap in this particular example.

Comment: The restriction is that if you ever decide to do create the key dynamically, e.g. discover that you need something like `map.insert(format!("id-{}", id).as_str(), value))`, you'll be greeted by a borrow checker error that you won't be able to resolve in an obvious way.

Answer (score 2):

The restriction is that it can only work with `str` with `'static` lifetimes, or that otherwise have lifetimes exceeding the entire lifetime of the `HashMap`. If you read a `String` from a file in a method and add a `str` based on it to an existing `HashMap`, then discard the `String`, that's a lifetime violation that Rust will flag.

If you're definitely using nothing but hardcoded literal strings, you're fine! Go forth and avoid some copies. But you're not wildly off the function of `enum`s at that point, so it's not as helpful, and it heavily restricts legal keys without `'static` lifetimes, which is what the warning you read is talking about.

Comment: If your strings can all be hardcoded you should probably just be using a struct.