# Value does not live long enough

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrowing

I don't completely understand lifetimes, but I think `b`'s lifetime will end before `self`'s.

So, how to edit this code? Do I copy something in memory? If I make a new instance, this lifetime must adhere to this case.

```
pub struct Formater {
    layout: &'static str,
}

impl Formater {
    pub fn new(layout: &'static str) -> Formater {
        let regex = Regex::new(r"%\{([a-z]+)(?::(.*?[^\\]))?\}").unwrap();
        let b = regex.replace_all(layout, "{}");

        return Formater {
            layout: &b,
        };
    }
}
```

The error:

```
error: `b` does not live long enough
  --> src/format.rs:16:22
   |
16 |             layout: &b,
   |                      ^ does not live long enough
17 |         };
18 |     }
   |     - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
   = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
```

Comment: You should make `layout` a `String` instead of `&'static str`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/rust-string-versus-str

Comment: thanks,this can help me do it.but,if i want use &str.how to do it?rust cannot direct edit lifetime？

Comment: @彭灵俊 why do you want to use `&str`?

Comment: i dont get the part where the `&'` in Formater could be used with `b` since b is not a static str, you could not have a static reference to it right?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The scope of `b` is the `new` function, so its memory will be freed when the function returns. But you are trying to return a reference to `b` from that function. If Rust let you do this, the only code that could possibly use that reference would use it *after* the value is invalid. The borrow checker is protecting you from *undefined behaviour*.

Making `layout` to be `&'static str` sounds like you are making things simple, but it is unreasonable to expect the dynamically allocated memory from `regex.replace_all` to be static. Without getting into `unsafe` code, you should consider anything in the `'static`  lifetime to be a compile-time constant. For example, a string literal.

As others have said, you probably want `layout` to be a `String`. A `String` is similar to `&str`, but it *owns* the underlying `str`. That means when you move the `String`, the underlying `str` moves with it. A `&str` is a reference and must not outlive the owner of the `str` that it points to.

---

If you really want it to be `&str`, an alternative but less ergonomic approach is to have the caller of `new()` own the `&str`, and pass it in as a mutable reference.

```
pub struct Formatter<'a> {
    layout: &'a str,
}

impl <'a> Formatter<'a> {
    pub fn new(layout: &'a mut &str) -> Formatter<'a> {
        let regex = Regex::new(r"%\{([a-z]+)(?::(.*?[^\\]))?\}").unwrap();
        *layout = regex.replace_all(layout, "{}");

        return Formatter {
            layout: layout,
        };
    }
}
```

This moves the problem one layer up the call stack and means that the reference you pass to `new` will be mutated by `new`.

```
pub fn main() {
    let mut s = "blah %{blah}";
    {
        let formatter = Formatter::new(&mut s);
        println!("{:?}", formatter.layout); // "blah {}"
    }
    println!("{:?}", s); // "blah {}"
}
```

Now `s` is owned by `main`, so `formatter` is valid as long as it is used only in a smaller scope than `main`.

But overall, I think this method is messier and you should just stick with `String` unless you have a good reason.

Comment: `layout: &'a mut &str`. I don't quite understand how there can be two ampersands in the type signature. I quite new to Rust. Is one for burrow and the other a reference? Aren't burrows references? I am confused.

Comment: @Lunfel A reference is a borrow. This is a reference of a reference. So it is a borrow on the borrow. All checks out.