# Variable doesn't live long enough in map

Tags: rust

I'm trying to turn a matrix A into matrix B where B_11 would be the biggest element of the first row and the smallest element of the second row in a tuple. So the matrix [1,2;3,4] would become [(2,1), (2,2); (4,1), (4,2)].

```
pub fn find_saddle_points(input: &[Vec<u64>]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let answer = Vec::new();
    println!("matrix: {:?}", input);
    let x: Vec<Vec<_>> = input
        .iter()
        .map(|row| {
            row.iter()
                .map(move |_| {
                    let y = get_column(&input, 0);
                    println!("y is {:?}", y);
                    let x = get_lowest(&y);
                    (get_highest(row), x)
                }).collect()
        }).collect();
    println!("x is {:?}", x);
    answer
}

fn get_highest(row: &Vec<u64>) -> &u64 {
    row.iter().max().unwrap()
}

fn get_lowest(column: &Vec<u64>) -> &u64 {
    column.iter().min().unwrap()
}

fn get_column(matrix: &[Vec<u64>], index: usize) -> Vec<u64> {
    matrix.iter().map(|row| row[index]).collect()
}
```

I'm getting an error messages when I try to use `y`:

```
error[E0597]: `y` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:11:41
   |
11 |                     let x = get_lowest(&y);
   |                                         ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
12 |                     (get_highest(row), x)
13 |                 }).collect()
   |                 - `y` dropped here while still borrowed
...
17 | }
   | - borrowed value needs to live until here
```

I don't understand why the value `y` has to live until after it's used. Isn't it enough that it lives until after the `get_lowest` function?
How would I fix this?

Comment: *I don't understand why the value `y` has to live until after it's used* — can you clarify what you mean? How would *any* program work if the variable was not available when it needs to be used?

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec) or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Value does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42503296/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR — you created the `Vec` `y` and then got a reference to the vector via `get_highest` and `get_lowest`. When you exit the closure, `Vec` is destroyed and the references would point at nothing. The compiler is preventing you from making a massive mistake that would lead to memory unsafety in a language like C or C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `clone()` function to pass new copies of the vectors to the functions `get_highest` and `get_lowest` and make the functions return integers and not references with the funciton `to_owned()`.

```
pub fn find_saddle_points(input: &[Vec<u64>]) -> Vec<(usize, usize)> {
    let answer = Vec::new();
    println!("matrix: {:?}", input);
    let x: Vec<Vec<_>> = input
        .iter()
        .map(|row| {
            row.iter()
                .map(move |_| {
                    let y = get_column(&input, 0);
                    println!("y is {:?}", y);
                    let x = get_lowest(y.clone());
                    (get_highest(row), x)
                }).collect()
        }).collect();
    println!("x is {:?}", x);
    answer
}

fn get_highest(row: Vec<u64>) -> u64 {
    row.iter().max().unwrap().to_owned()
}

fn get_lowest(column: Vec<u64>) -> u64 {
    column.iter().min().unwrap().to_owned()
}

fn get_column(matrix: &[Vec<u64>], index: usize) -> Vec<u64> {
    matrix.iter().map(|row| row[index]).collect()
}
```

And as @shepmaster posted, you should avoid using references of Vectors as function parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Shepmaster explained it well

> TL;DR — you created the Vec y and then got a reference to the vector
>   via get_highest and get_lowest. When you exit the closure, Vec is
>   destroyed and the references would point at nothing. The compiler is
>   preventing you from making a massive mistake that would lead to memory
>   unsafety in a language like C or C++.