# read file from random Vec of string

Tags: rust, lifetime

i want to read a file randomly from `Vec<String>` and then use it as multipart to reqwest async

but i keep getting:
[image: borrowed value doesn't live long enough]

here's the function

```rust
fn getFiles(dirname: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut items: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let dir = std::fs::read_dir(dirname);
    for item in dir.expect("fail") {
        if let Ok(item) = item {
            items.push(item.path().into_os_string().into_string().unwrap());
        }
    }
    items
}
    // call the function
    let dir_items = getFiles("src/assets");
    let file = dir_items.into_iter().choose(&mut rand::thread_rng()).unwrap();
    let path = std::path::Path::new(&file);
    let sub_file = std::fs::read(path)?;
    // after this, file lifetime is already end ?
    let sub_file_part = reqwest::multipart::Part::bytes(sub_file)
        .file_name(path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy())
        .mime_str("application/octet-stream")?;
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=794ef871fd563d3acddd70a2ff9d7c01)

Comment: I am not familiar with `rust`, but the SO & Google are. Did you read [Value does not live long enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503296/value-does-not-live-long-enough)

Comment: [Playground link with a bit of additional stuff so that it compiles (or at least fails where it should)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=794ef871fd563d3acddd70a2ff9d7c01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at this piece by piece:

```rust
let path = std::path::Path::new(&file);
```

If you have a look at [the documentation for `Path::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.new), you see the following signature:

```rust
pub fn new<S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &S) -> &Path
```

After applying the second [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision), (quote: "if there is exactly one input lifetime parameter, that lifetime is assigned to all output lifetime parameters: `fn foo<'a>(x: &'a i32) -> &'a i32`"), this signature really looks like this:

```rust
pub fn new<'a, S: AsRef<OsStr> + ?Sized>(s: &'a S) -> &'a Path
```

So, your `path` variable cannot live longer than your `file` variable.

Next, this is relevant:

```rust
.file_name(path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy())
```

After again applying the lifetime elision rules, you can see that calling [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap) on [`path.file_name()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/path/struct.Path.html#method.file_name) gives you a [`&std::ffi::OsStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html) that can live no longer than your `path` variable which in turn (as discussed before) can live no longer than your `file` variable. So, transitively, `path.filename().unwrap()` can live no longer than the `file` variable.

Now, let's have a look at the signature of [`OsStr::to_string_lossy()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.to_string_lossy):

```rust
pub fn to_string_lossy(&self) -> Cow<'_, str>
```

So, this method returns a `Cow<'_, str>`. `Cow` is shorthand for "Copy or Owned" – meaning that the `Cow` can either contain a reference to the data (in this case, a `&str`, if the `OsStr` contained only valid UTF-8 bytes) or it can own the data itself (in this case, by containing a `String`, if the `OsStr` contained data that needed to be converted or to be filtered out during UTF-8 conversion).

`'_` [is a placeholder and means that the compiler shall (again) infer the lifetime with the lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/lifetime-elision.html?highlight=inferred%20lifetime#default-trait-object-lifetimes). The expanded signature looks like this:

```
pub fn to_string_lossy<'a>(&'a self) -> Cow<'a, str>
```

So, in your example, `'a` can't be any bigger than the lifetime of your `&OsStr` returned by `unwrap()`, which transitively means that `'a` can't be bigger than the lifetime of `file`.

However, [`reqwest::multipart::Part::file_name()`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/0.11.4/reqwest/multipart/struct.Part.html#method.file_name) expects something implementing `Into<Cow<'static, str>>` as parameter. Our `Cow<'a, str>` definitively can't implement that, as our `file` variable is not alive until the end of the program. If it *was* alive until the end of the program, our `Cow` would implement it because `file` could be borrowed for `'static`, and all would be well – this is the reason for the error message.

You can work around this by calling [`into_owned()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html#method.into_owned) on the `Cow`. This converts the `Cow` into a string, which *does* implement `Into<Cow<'static, str>>`:

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;

fn getFiles(dirname: &str) -> Vec<String> {
    let mut items: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let dir = std::fs::read_dir(dirname);
    for item in dir.expect("fail") {
        if let Ok(item) = item {
            items.push(item.path().into_os_string().into_string().unwrap());
        }
    }
    items
}

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    // call the function
    let dir_items = getFiles("src/assets");
    let file = dir_items.into_iter().choose(&mut rand::thread_rng()).unwrap();
    let path = std::path::Path::new(&file);
    let sub_file = std::fs::read(path)?;
    // after this, file lifetime is already end ?
    let sub_file_part = reqwest::multipart::Part::bytes(sub_file)
        .file_name(path.file_name().unwrap().to_string_lossy().into_owned())
        .mime_str("application/octet-stream")?;
    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=13989db75684031bdfbdd568d6c12571)

Comment: @bren Yeah, lifetimes can be quite tricky to get right (and sometimes give less than helpful error messages). But it gets easier with more experience ;-)