# Why does a &str not coerce to a &String when using Vec::contains?

Tags: string, rust

A friend asked me to explain the following quirk in Rust. I was unable to, hence this question:

```
fn main() {
    let l: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    //let ret = l.contains(&String::from(func())); // works
    let ret = l.contains(func());  // does not work
    println!("ret: {}", ret);
}

fn func() -> & 'static str {
    "hello"
}
```

[Example on the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=de5aa44b610d166c2a55fb9f8910099a&version=stable)

The compiler will complain like this:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:26
  |
4 |     let ret = l.contains(func());  // does not work
  |                          ^^^^^^ expected struct `std::string::String`, found str
  |
  = note: expected type `&std::string::String`
             found type `&'static str`
```

In other words, `&str` does not coerce with `&String`.

At first I thought it was to do with `'static`, however that is a red herring.

The commented line fixes the example at the cost of an extra allocation.

My questions:

- Why doesn't `&str` coerce with `&String`?
- Is there a way to make the call to `contains` work without the extra allocation?

Comment: http://www.ameyalokare.com/rust/2017/10/12/rust-str-vs-String.html
Seems like String coerces to str but not the other way around.

Comment: [Vec::contains is too restrictive](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42671) is also relevant. The short of it is, fixing this so contains can make the comparable references is possible, but it broke other code. A very Rust gotcha.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Comment: I think it's more subtle than that. We know the difference between `String` and `str`. It's a question of coercion.

Comment: @EddBarrett I think that my answer clearly clarifies why it does not make sense for `str` to coerce to `String`, and also how you could change your code to avoid allocation.

Comment: *I don't think the possible duplicate answers my question* — if you spend more time having a useful, distinctive title, false duplicates will be less common.

Comment: Note that [the function has nothing to do with the problem](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b65a8ea4d0c788f8c861503a6ce11001&version=stable).

Comment: We've just found https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42671

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that the Rust developers [intend to adjust the signature of `contains` to allow the example posted above to work](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/42671).

In some sense, this is a known bug in `contains`. It sounds like the fix won't allow those types to coerce, but will allow the above example to work.

Answer (score 11):

Your first question should be answer already by @Marko.

Your second question, should be easy to answer as well, just use a closure:

`let ret = l.iter().any(|x| x == func());`

### Edit:

Not the "real" answer anymore, but I let this here for people who might be interested in a solution for this.

Comment: It's true that you have worked around the issue, but that's not quite what I meant. Can you do it still using `contains`?

Comment: I'm afraid no, but what's the difference in your eyes? Both do the same :)

Comment: Practically you are right, but it doesn't help me understand the type system restrictions at play here.

Comment: Ok, but your question was: `Is there a way to make the code work without the extra allocation?` I answered that, I get a downvote? Okay :/ Go on

Comment: FWIW it wasn't me who downvoted. I'll revise my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the imputation. :)

Answer (score 3):

`std::string::String` is a growable, heap-allocated data structure whereas string slice (`str`) is an immutable fixed-length string somewhere in memory. String slice is used as a borrowed type, via `&str`. Consider it as view to some string date that resides somewhere in memory. That is why it does not make sense for `str` to coerce to `String`, while the other way around perfectly makes sense. You have a heap-allocated `String` somewhere in memory and you want to use a view (a string slice) to that string.

To answer your second question. There is no way to make the code work in the current form. You either need to change to a vector of string slices (that way, there will be no extra allocation) or use something other then `contains` method.

Comment: I don't think this quite answers my question. Both `&str` and `&String` are borrowed types.

Comment: @EddBarrett You are right. I hope the edited answer now answers your question.