# Rust: How does a reference to a String become a string slice?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand the concept of strings and string slices.

```
fn say_hello_slice(slice: &str) {
    println!("Hey {}", slice);
}

fn say_hello_string(string: &String) {
    println!("{:?}", string);
}

fn print_int(int_ref: &i32) {
    println!("{:?}", int_ref);
}

fn main() {
    let slice: &str = "you";
    let s: String = String::from("String");
    say_hello_slice(slice);
    say_hello_slice(&s);

    let number: i32 = 12345;
    print_int(&number);

    say_hello_string(&s);
}
```

This program gives the below output when I compile and run:

```
Hey you
Hey String
12345
"String"
```

I understand that when `&` is added to the binding it becomes a reference to its binding type. For example, `&` to `number` in above program becomes `&i32`.

I don't understand how it works when I add `&` to `String` and it becomes `&str`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have just witnessed the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) trait. This trait has three uses:

- Conversion to another type when dereferencing (the `*` operator)
- Automatic conversion if necessary (coercion) when borrowing
- You can call methods of another type directly.

In your case, because `String` implements `Deref<Target = str>` this means that `&s` is coerced into a `&str`.

More info [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#deref).