# Why can size_of be used on unsized types?

Tags: memory, rust

The [documentation for `std::mem::size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) doesn't provide an example of `&str` or `String` being used, but both return sizes with the following code:

```
println!("The size of a string slice (&str): {}", mem::size_of::<&str>());
// OUTPUT: The size of a string slice (&str): 16
println!("The size of a growable string (String): {}", mem::size_of::<String>());
// OUTPUT: The size of a growable string (String): 24
```

From my understanding, a `&str` type is just a reference to the beginning of a ["sequence of Unicode scalar values encoded as a stream of UTF-8 bytes"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/strings.html). Is `&str` referring to the size of two pointers? I know a pointer is 8 bytes long on a 64-bit system.

`mem::size_of::<str>()` does return an error, like I would have expected. However, both `String` and `&String` return sizes.

Comment: _"From my understanding, a &str type is just a reference to the beginning of"_ No, a string slice needs to record the beginning and the length of the string. Rust does not use null-terminated strings (unless with `CStr`).

Comment: Note that [`size_of_val`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of_val.html) exists, for when you have a reference to an unsized type and you want to know the size of the referent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why can size_of be used on unsized types?

It cannot. If it *could*, it would be defined as:

```
pub const fn size_of<T: ?Sized>() -> usize
//                    ^^^^^^^^
```

> Why can size_of be used on [`&str` / `String` / `&String`]?

`&str`, `String`, and `&String` are all sized types.

A `&str` is essentially:

```
struct StringSlice {
    ptr: *const u8,
    len: usize,
}
```

A `String` is essentially:

```
struct String {
    ptr: *const u8,
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
}
```

A `&String` is essentially:

```
struct StringRef {
    ptr: *const String,
}
```

> referring to the size of two pointers

A `usize` is an integer type that is guaranteed to be the size of a native pointer, so... kind of?

See also:

- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24158114/155423)