# Takes slice ([ia..ib]) on a string slice (&str) returns a str

Tags: rust, slice

I am learning `Rust` and I've encountered this when I was trying out examples:

```
fn main() {

    let x: &str = "hello";  // We created a string slice, `&str`
    let y: &str = x[2..4];  // I was expecting `y` to be `&str` as well
    // let y: str = x[2..4];  // `y` is actually a str (DST)!
    
    let z: &str = &x[2..4];  // This gives me what I expected!

    println!("str value: {}", z);
}
```

I am a fairly confused [edited] in the first place; wasn't `x` a slice already? why would I need to append the ampersand again in the last statement to make z a string slice (which in my mind it looks like `&(&x)` or just `&&x`)?

Related content that'd help you get grasp of the answer:

1. [**Why can't we move out of index (SO)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904864/what-does-cannot-move-out-of-index-of-mean)
2. [**SO example of the `impl` of `Index` (SO)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27879161/what-is-the-return-type-of-the-indexing-operation)
3. [**Move and Copy Semantics in Rust (Rust Book)**](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html?highlight=it%27s%20moved#variables-and-data-interacting-with-clone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a bit stunned in the first place; wasn't x a slice already?

Yes?

> why would I need to append the ampersand again in the last statement to make z a string slice?

Because [that's how indexing is defined in the language](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html).

> `container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)`[...]. This allows nice things such as `let value = v[index]` if the type of value implements `Copy`.

And that's why you have to re-reference owned types or DSTs coming out of an indexing operation.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: reading the index docs I understand that `container.index(index)` returns a reference to the value we want access to; hence the deference symbol at the front(`*`); because the size at compile time has to be known (i.e., `[..]`), DSTs are not allowed in this case. But I am still not see clearly how this is related to my example above. Could you expand on your answer with an example? What is `x[2..4]` and `&x[2..4]` expand to?  Thanks very much!

Comment: `x[2..4]` expands to `*x.index(2..4)`, which uses `impl<T, I> Index<I> for [T] where     I: SliceIndex<[T]> { type Output = <I as SliceIndex<[T]>>::Output }`, and that calls `impl<T> SliceIndex<[T]> for Range<usize> { type Output = [T] }`. So `x.index(2..4)` returns a `&[T]`, which is the dereferenced to `[T]`. `&[2..4]` literally just adds a reference (`&`) in front of that which basically cancels out the dereference (not entirely true, but works well enough for this case)

Comment: I've now come to terms with your explanations (and in a way understood it): there really isn't much reasoning (not that this was an easy decision on the design when Rust was created, I am sure there's good debate behind this at the outset); like you said, it is what the language decides to do, it's the rule. `v[index]` is going to expand to `*v.index(index)[..]` in Rust, and nothing more; if we want to get the reference of it, we'll have to add `&` in front of it.

Comment: One more question though, you mentioned "that's why you have to re-reference owned types"; in my example, do we own `x`? Slice is but a fat pointer (two words), right? here's a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225055/in-rust-can-you-own-a-string-literal) related to this.

Comment: No, here it's the second case, `x[..]` is a DST so you have to reference it. The owned case would be a `Vec<String>` indexed with an integer, `*container.index(usize)` will have type `String`, but you can't move the string out of the original reference (and thus vector) so you need to re-reference it and get an `&String`.

Comment: I see; the official docs went as far as `*container.index(index)` and here you added an extra `[..]`(i.e., taking a full slice); are you implying that this is done by default as part of the syntax sugar, in the case of DST (but not the owned types)?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking about. The result of `Index::index` method is dereferenced always, that's how indexing desugars, it does not matter whether it's a Copy type, a DST, or an affine type. `x[..]` is just an example of slicing a thing.

Comment: The quoted section from you answer has included `[..]` for syntax sugar; `[..]` isn't part of the syntax sugar in original documentation for `Index` (at least I couldn't find it); unless, `*container.index(index)` and `*container.index(index)[..]` are actually the same. I am not sure whether they are the same. Hope this help a little bit.

Comment: That is not a slice, it's an ellipsis I just happen to have forgotten a period in (also per MLA there should be a space between each bracket and dot but nobody's got time for dat). If you open the link, you'll see that there is text I removed from the quote because it's not germane to the answer. I fixed the ellipsis (added the missing dot, not all the spaces).