# Why is `str` encapsulated inside `String` instead of inside a `Box<str>`?

Tags: string, rust, smart-pointers

It's not causing me any difficulties — I am perfectly capable of using `String` — but is there any reason that `str` is encapsulated in its own special type rather than inside the more general `Box` type? If there *is* a reason then the answer might help me model how to work with `Box` differently.

Why is `str` encapsulated inside `String` instead of inside a `Box<str>`? Is it simply for convenience of typing such a common structure or is there a deeper reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Comment: why vector is a vector and not a `Box<slice>` ?

Comment: Note that `Box<str>` is a perfectly valid and occasionally useful type. It's not a "rather than", but "as well as"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`String` is more like a `Vec<char>` than a `Box<str>` - it has methods to push more `char`s on the end, or push a whole `str`. It has length and capacity, rather than only length. Like `Box` and `Vec`, it owns it's contents, and places them on the heap; unlike `Box`, it also extends the functionality of `str` beyond its inherent properties.

Comment: Ah, so perhaps I should now ask, why isn't it a `Vec<str>`? But thank you, I hadn't realized that requirement--though it's obvious in retrospect.

Comment: @LemmaPrism I'd quibble about `Vec<char>` and prefer to say `Vec<u8>` for reasons, but [`String` **is** literally a `Vec<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.36.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#283-285). The source is open and also linked from the docs; feel free to browse it.

Comment: @Shepmaster That's a fair point. I think I mean conceptually, `Vec<char>` is closer to the concept, but implementation-wise, `Vec<u8>` is literally true (and represents the memory footprint more accurately)

Comment: I've belated realized I said `Vec<str>` instead of `Vec<char>`; silly me. But yes, the source is surprisingly easy to review! And thank you @Zarenor for identifying the question I _should_ have asked.

Answer (score 5):

`str` mainly has `&self` methods because it cannot change any of the characters it contains because a change in a character might mean a change in the length, and it cannot reallocate itself. On the other hand `String` is like a `&mut str` because it provides methods to manipulate `str`s.

For example, you can [push](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.push_str) to it, or [replace a section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace_range).

On the other hand, a `Box<str>` provides none of this because it is essentially an owned `str` and so it only provides the `&self` methods I talked about earlier.