# Why does the &str primitive exist?

Tags: string, pointers, vector, rust, slice

If [`String` is actually](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/string.rs.html#283-285)

```
pub struct String {
    vec: Vec<u8>,
}
```

Then why is there a special syntax (`&str`) for a slice of a `Vec<u8>`? In Chapter 3 of [*"Programming Rust"* by Jim Blandy & Jason Orendorff](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-rust/9781491927274/ch03.html) it says,

> *`&str` is very much like `&[T]`: a fat pointer to some data. `String` is analogous to `Vec<T>`*

Following that statement there is a chart which shows all the ways they're similar, but there isn't any mention of a single method that they're different. Is a `&str;` just a `&[T]`?

Likewise  in the answer to, [*What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/124486) it says

> This is identical to the relationship between a vector `Vec<T>` and a slice `&[T]`, and is similar to the relationship between by-value `T` and by-reference `&T` for general types.

That question focuses on the difference between `String` and `&str`. Knowing that a `String` really is a vector of `u8`, I'm more interested in `&str`, which I can't even find the source to. Why does this primitive even exist when we have a primitive (implemented as a fat pointer) for regular vector slices?

Comment: I get the feeling you don't quite believe that `str` is to `String` as `[T]` is to `Vec<T>`. `[T]` is built-in, just like `str` -- you wouldn't be able to find the source for `[T]` in the standard library. But you seem to be confused about `String`, and not about `Vec` -- can you articulate why?

Comment: your question could be why not use `*mut u8`... This is basic object concept. String is a mutable UTF-8, `str` is a no mutable UTF-8. It's two type because it's represent two different thing. If we use `Vec<u8>` what guarantee would we have that it's a utf-8 string ? none. The user would have to know that. That the C way;

Comment: @Stargateur to which the answer would be: because *pointer* dereferencing is impossible in safe rust.

Answer (score 9):

It exists for the same reason that `String` exists, and we don't just pass around `Vec<u8>` for every string.

- A `String` is an owned, growable container of data that **is guaranteed to be UTF-8**.
- `&str` is a borrowed, fixed-length container of data that **is guaranteed to be UTF-8**
- A `Vec<u8>` is an owned, growable container of `u8`.
- `&[u8]` is a borrowed, fixed-length container of `u8`.

This is effectively the reason that types exist, period — to provide abstraction and guarantees (a.k.a. restrictions) on a looser blob of bits.

If we had access to the string as `&mut [u8]`, then we could trivially ruin the UTF-8 guarantee, which is why all such methods are marked as `unsafe`. Even with an immutable `&[u8]`, we wouldn't be able to make assumptions (a.k.a. optimizations) about the data and would have to write much more defensive code everywhere.

> but there isn't any mention of a single method that they're different

Looking at the documentation for [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) and [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) quickly shows a number of methods that exist on one that don't exist on the other, so I don't understand your statement. `split_last` is the first one that caught my eye, for example.

Comment: Could you add to your 4 points above another pair of points for `Vector<char>` vs `[char]` for clarity? Perhaps that would help me refine my question. I didn't compute that `&str` is a strongly typed pointer to UTF-8, whereas `String` is just a type with the constraint in it's constructor and that we would need the ability to differentiate `&mut [u8]` from a subtype that has to be constructed as UTF-8.

Comment: @EvanCarroll a `Vec<char>` / `&[char]` don't have any real relation to `String` / `str`. At best, they would be a UTF-32 string, but generally there's no use for such a type. *`String` [...] constraint in it's constructor* — and every mutating method.

Answer (score 7):

`&str` is not necessarily a view to a `String`, it can be a view to anything that is a valid UTF-8 string.

For example, the crate [arraystring](https://crates.io/crates/arraystring) allows creating a string on the stack that can be [viewed as a `&str`](https://docs.rs/arraystring/0.3.0/arraystring/struct.ArrayString.html#impl-AsRef%3Cstr%3E).

Comment: More common is a string literal, which is also not a `String`.

Comment: @Shepmaster Very true. I should have think about it first.