# String concatenation in rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to get a &str and &str to concatenate in a for loop withe intention of using the new combined string after a number of parts have been added to it. A general layout of the for loop can be seen below but I am having a lot of trouble combining strings due to numerous errors.

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    let split_line = line.unwrap().split(",");
    let mut edited_line = "";

    for word in split_line {
        if !word.contains("substring") {
            let test_string = [edited_line, word].join(",");
            edited_line = &test_string;
        }
    }
    let _ = writeln!(outfile, "{}", edited_line).expect("Unable to write to file"); 
}
```

First error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
```

Comes when running the above.

Second error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types expected &str, found struct std::string::String
```

happens when you remove the & from test_string when it is assigned to edited_line

Note: `format!` and `concat!` macros both also give error 2.
It seems to be if I get error 2 and convert the `std::string:String` and convert it to `&str` I get the error stating the variables don't live long enough.

How am I supposed to go about building a string of many parts?

Comment: What do you mean by `edited_line = &test_string;`? Do you mean `edited_like += test_string`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that Rust has two string types, `String` and `&str` (actually, there are more, but that's irrelevant here).

- `String` is an **owned string** and can grow and shrink dynamically.
- `&str` is a **borrowed string** and is immutable.

Calling `[edited_line, word].join(",")` creates a new `String`, which is allocated on the heap. `edited_line = &test_string` then borrows the `String` and implicitly converts it to a `&str`.

The problem is that its memory is freed as soon as the owner (`test_string`) goes out of scope, but the borrow lives longer than `test_string`. This is fundamentally impossible in Rust, since it would otherwise be a use-after-free bug.

The correct and most efficient way to do this is to create an empty `String` outside of the loop and only *append* to it in the loop:

```rust
let mut edited_line = String::new();

for word in split_line {
    if !word.contains("substring") {
        edited_line.push(',');
        edited_line.push_str(word);
    }
}
```

Note that the resulting string will start with a comma, which might not be desired. To avoid it, you can write

```rust
let mut edited_line = String::new();

for word in split_line {
    if !word.contains("substring") {
        if !edited_line.is_empty() {
            edited_line.push(',');
        }
        edited_line.push_str(word);
    }
}
```

This could be done more elegantly with the [`itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9/itertools) crate, which provides a `join` method for iterators:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

let edited_line: String = line
    .unwrap()
    .split(",")
    .filter(|word| !word.contains("substring"))
    .join(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

`let mut edited_line = "";` makes `edited_line` a `&str` with a static lifetime.

To actually make `edited_line` a string, either append `.to_owned()`, or use `String::new()`:

```
let mut edited_line = String::new();
// Or
let mut edited_line = "".to_owned();
```

See [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) if you are unfamiliar with the differences.

Most importantly for your case, you can't extend a `&str`, but you can extend a `String`.

---

Once you switched edited_line to a `String`, using the method of setting `edited_line` to `[edited_line, word].join(",");` works:

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    let split_line = line.unwrap().split(",");
    let mut edited_line = String::new();

    for word in split_line {
        if !word.contains("substring") {
            let test_string = [edited_line.as_str(), word].join(","); // Added .as_str() to edited_line
            edited_line = test_string; // Removed the & here
        }
    }
    let _ = writeln!(outfile, "{}", edited_line).expect("Unable to write to file"); 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9cc60c0d1576d6d80fbb720bfbde99f)

However, this is both not very efficient, nor ergonomic. Also it has the (probably unintended) result of prepending each line with a `,`.

---

Here is an alternative that uses only one `String` instance:

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    let split_line = line.unwrap().split(",");
    let mut edited_line = String::new();

    for word in split_line {
        if !word.contains("substring") {
            edited_line.push(',');
            edited_line.push_str(word);
        }
    }
    let _ = writeln!(outfile, "{}", edited_line).expect("Unable to write to file"); 
}
```

This still prepends the `,` character before each line however. You can probably fix that by checking if edited_line is not empty before pushing the `,`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7c04868f8f9c254164acd485c4efc02)

---

The third option is to change the for loop into an iterator:

```
for line in reader.lines() {
    let edited_line = line.split(",")
        .filter(|word| !word.contains("substring"))
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>() // Collecting allows us to use the join function.
        .join(",");
    let _ = writeln!(outfile, "{}", edited_line).expect("Unable to write to file"); 
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5481756afa305c4b3526f4bb590fda26)

This way we can use the join function as intended, neatly eliminating the initial `,` at the start of each line.

---

PS: If you have trouble knowing what types each variable is, I suggest using an IDE like [Intellij-rust](https://intellij-rust.github.io/), which shows type hints for each variable as you write them.