# Solving a borrow issue with a HashMap (spoilers for the Advent of Code 2020)

Tags: rust

First time poster and very new to Rust. I have been slowly toying with Rust for the past few months and I am just recently making a solid effort to learn the language. To help me with this I'm planning to do all the problems for this years [Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/) in Rust. Currently I'm stuck on the fourth day. If you would like to read about it [here is the link](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/4). Obviously I might be spoiling this problem for some of you so be warned! Anyways on to the problem!

For this problem I decided to use a HashMap to solve part one. I come from Java and Python, so I figured Rust's HashMap would work similarly to Java and Python's dictionary. I realize that this might not be the best solution but I wanted to try it anyway to learn about HashMaps. Here is the code I came up with. I tried to comment the code so it was easier to understand.

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn check_passport_valid(passport: HashMap<&str, &str>) -> bool {
    return true;
}

fn main() {
    // set up a bufReader to read the data
    let data = "data/data.txt";
    let file = File::open(data).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // init a mutable HashMap 
    let mut passport: HashMap<&str, &str> = HashMap::new();
    let mut count = 0;

    // read the data in line by line
    for line in reader.lines() {
        // not sure if i should &line.unwrap() or do this
        // seems to work the same in both situations
        let s = line.unwrap();

        // if line is blank check password and init new HashMap
        if "" == s {
            if check_passport_valid(passport) { count += 1; }
            passport = HashMap::new();
        } 
        
        // else put values into HashMap
        else {
            // first split into items
            let items: Vec<&str> = s.split(' ').collect();
            for item in items {
                // split into key/value pair
                let pair: Vec<&str> = item.split(':').collect();
                passport.insert(pair[0], pair[1]);
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{}", count);
}
```

As you can see its not done, but with this I get the following error:

```
error[E0597]: `s` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:34:36
   |
27 |             if check_passport_valid(passport) { count += 1; }
   |                                     -------- borrow later used here
...
34 |             let items: Vec<&str> = s.split(' ').collect();
   |                                    ^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
41 |     }
   |     - `s` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I have tried played around with borrowing different values but I can't seem to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's best to read the whole input into a `String` first. This will avoid the borrow checker error: `let data = std::fs::read_to_string("data/data.txt").unwrap();`

Comment: P.S. [Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f94e5730c143a813b21b245e15c72fd9) a solution that minimizes memory allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is that the values you get from `s.split(' ')` are slices of the `lines` variable, which essentially mean that they reference the `lines` variable. At the end of the loop, the `lines` variable is dropped and replaced by the next line, which invalidates all the references to it. The easiest way is to convert the `&str` to a `String` (an owned type) with `.to_owned()`, so it copies the data to a static memory location which is no longer dependent on the `lines` variable:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::collections::HashMap;

// this is now HashMap<String, String> instead of HashMap<&str, &str>
fn check_passport_valid(passport: HashMap<String, String>) -> bool {
    return true;
}

fn main() {
    let data = "data/data.txt";
    let file = File::open(data).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // this is now HashMap<String, String> instead of HashMap<&str, &str>
    let mut passport: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    let mut count = 0;

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let s = line.unwrap();

        if "" == s {
            if check_passport_valid(passport) { count += 1; }
            passport = HashMap::new();
        } 
        
        else {
            let items: Vec<&str> = s.split(' ').collect();
            for item in items {
                let pair: Vec<&str> = item.split(':').collect();
                // call to_owned on both elements
                passport.insert(pair[0].to_owned(), pair[1].to_owned());
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{}", count);
}
```

Read more about `str` vs `String` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/5923139).