# Rust - How are 'String' and 'str' different in memory?

Tags: rust

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) question, but still didn't get it, so here's what I know (it might be incorrect):

- Initializing a variable of type `String` allocates memory on the *heap* and stores a pointer to that memory on the *stack*.
- Initializing a variable of type `&str` stores a pointer on the *stack*, and I'm assuming that pointer **points** to a `str` on the *heap*.

If that's the case - if both `String` and `&str` store pointers on the stack **pointing** to memory locations on the heap - does that mean `String` and `str` (not the reference) are the same?

Comment: &str can point anywhere. It can point to .data segment of the executable in case of string literals. It can point to a buffer on the heap owned by some String. It can point to a mmap'd file. `str` meanwhile is literally just a contiguous region of bytes.

Comment: @IvanC Thank you for your answer, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This article explains quite well, and has some visuals as to how both work : https://blog.thoughtram.io/string-vs-str-in-rust/.

To answer your question, no they are not the same. They can just point to the same thing.

A `String` is a container which stores text using `str`s. It owns the data it points to, and can modify it or add/remove from it.

From the article, a `str` is :

> String slices (or str) are what we work with when we either reference
> a range of UTF-8 text that is “owned” by someone else, or when we
> create them using string literals.

So `str` only points to data, and can point to a substring of some data as well. But it doesn't own the data and can't modify it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is well explained. You said `str` only points to data and cannot modify it, but I'm new to Rust and have noticed that this compiles just fine `let mut name: &str = "Jake Gyllenhall"; name = "Tom Holland";`. Could you please explain what is happening here?

Comment: This is because of the variable binding, you're changing what the variable points to, but not the underlying data. When you're assigning to name, you're changing the previous pointer with the new pointer. See here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=08efc22dac55216e101af3ac6eeed394, I output the address, you can see it changes each time.

Comment: Put simply: `String` [is literally `Vec<u8>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/src/alloc/string.rs.html#279-281), and `&str` [is literally `&[u8]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.48.0/src/core/str/converts.rs.html#161-165).