# How to create and return a string vector

Tags: string, vector, rust

I am trying to make a function in Rust that returns a string vector. This is what I have so far:

```
fn letters() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push("a");
    v.push("b");
    v
}
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", letters());
}
```

This is the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
1 | fn letters() -> Vec<String> {
  |                 ----------- expected `Vec<String>` because of return type
...
5 |     v
  |     ^ expected struct `String`, found `&str`
  |
  = note: expected struct `Vec<String>`
             found struct `Vec<&str>`
```

I have been struggling with this. It seems that the only way I can solve the problem is by declaring the vector in a different way but I need to declare it the way I did.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Strings are definitely a challenging part of Rust for many people, so there are a lot of questions about issues like this. You might find it useful to read [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"a".to_string()`.

```rust
fn letters() -> Vec<String> {
    let mut v = Vec::new();
    v.push("a".to_string());
    v.push("b".to_string());
    v
}
fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", letters());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am new to rust and this has been so difficult for me.