# Modify string inside a Vec<&str> in rust and general ownership confusion

Tags: regex, string, rust

I'm new to rust and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around ownership concepts. I have a string that has substrings with a specific pattern inside of it, like "alice [bob] charlie [dave]", and I'm trying to get to a vector of strings that looks like ("john","dave"). My first go was at using a regex with non capturing groups, but I can't get that to work, because I don't really understand rust very well:

```
let re = Regex::new(r"(?:\[)([a-zA-Z]+)(?:])").unwrap();
let mut answer: Vec<&str> = re.captures_iter((&text)).map(|capGroup| &*String::from(&capGroup[1])).collect();
```

But I could collect them like so:

```
let re = Regex::new(r"\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+]").unwrap();
let mut answer: Vec<&str> = re.find_iter((&text)).map(|mtc| mtc.as_str()).collect();
```

The problem with this, is that it leaves me with ("[bob]","[dave]"), and I've also been unsucessuful at trimming the first and last few characters of the string. As a matter of fact, I don't even understand how iterating works here it seems, because when I try to do:

```
 let mut it = answer.iter();
 for name in &mut it{
      ...
```

I end up with name being of type `&&str` instead of the `&str` that I expected.
So my questions would be:

- How do I use capture groups in rust for what I'm trying to do in the first example, in an idiomatic fashion? I feel like I'm close to the mark of applying something to all the captures and collecting into a vec but something is escaping me.
- Given `Vec<&str>`, how do I modify the strings inside it? What is it that I'm missing here?
- Why is my iteration item of type `&&str` when I do that?
- Is there a better way overall of achieving this in rust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `"[]"`, you can add a capturing group in your regular expression and then filter only the matches that are captured by it:

```
let text = "alice bob [charlie] dave [emily]";

let re = Regex::new(r"\[([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)]").unwrap();
let answer: Vec<&str> = re
    .captures_iter(text)
    .filter_map(|capture| capture.get(1))
    .map(|mtch| mtch.as_str())
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", answer); // ["charlie", "emily"]
```

`Capture::get` returns an `Option` so you can use that with `filter_map` to filter out all of the matches that aren't captured there, since `capture.get(1)` will return `None` for those.

---

To answer the other question, the reason why the items in the iterator are of type `&&str` is because the vector contains `&str`, but you are iterating over a reference to the vector so everything is doubly borrowed.

These borrow the vector so you are iterating over `&&str`:

```
for item in &answer {
    // item is &&str
}

// which is syntactic sugar for:
for item in (&answer).into_iter() {
    // item is &&str
}

for item in answer.iter() {
    // item is &&str
}
```

This iterates over `&str`, but *moves* the vector so you can't use it again:

```
for item in answer {
    // item is &str
}

// is sugar for:
for item in answer.into_iter() {
    // item is &str
}
```

You can iterate over `&str` without moving the vector by copying the slices. This is cheap because only the pointer is copied:

```
for item in answer.iter().copied() {
    // item is &str
}
```

Having `&&str` instead of `&str` is almost never a problem. Methods of `&str` can still be called on a `&&str` and you can always just dereference it with `*` if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Just some general information: In rust `&str` is just a reference to a string slice, meaning there is no ownership of the pointing variable. So in your example `let mut answer: Vec<&str>`  the mutable variable `answer` doesn't own any of the slices in the `Vec`. Since the `&str` 's are non-mutable `str` references,you would need ownership in order to mutate them. So you could convert them into a `String` object with the `.to_owned()` function. String slices(`&str`) and Strings(`String`) are completely different in rust. Here is a good explanation: [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str).

1. For your question "Why is my iteration item of type &&str when I do that?", you are referencing(`&`) a reference to a string slice(`&str`).
2. For your question "Given Vec<&str>, how do I modify the strings inside it? What is it that I'm missing here?" a way to go about this is to use the `String` struct.