# About the change of the ownership of the array and vec

Tags: rust

This code causes a error. It seems reasonable, because the ownership has moved:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = vec![1, 2];
    let mut arr2 = vec![2, 6];
    arr = arr2;
    arr2[1] = 2;
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `arr2`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
3 |     let mut arr2 = vec![2, 6];
  |         -------- move occurs because `arr2` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4 |     arr = arr2;
  |           ---- value moved here
5 |     arr2[1] = 2;
  |     ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

This code won't cause an error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = [1, 2];
    let mut arr2 = [2, 4];
    arr = arr2;
    arr2[1] = 2;
}
```

This will cause an error:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = ["1".to_string(), "2".to_string()];
    let mut arr2 = ["2".to_string(), "4".to_string()];
    arr = arr2;
    arr2[1] = "2".to_string();
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `arr2`
 --> src/main.rs:5:5
  |
3 |     let mut arr2 = ["2".to_string(), "4".to_string()];
  |         -------- move occurs because `arr2` has type `[String; 2]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
4 |     arr = arr2;
  |           ---- value moved here
5 |     arr2[1] = "2".to_string();
  |     ^^^^^^^ value used here after move
```

This works fine...

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut arr = ["1", "2"];
    let mut arr2 = ["2", "4"];
    arr = arr2;
    arr2[1] = "2";
}
```

I am completely confused.

Comment: `Vec` does not implement `Copy`.  Arrays of `T` implement `Copy` if `T: Copy`.  `String` does not implement `Copy`, but integers and shared references do.  Therefore your arrays of integers and `&str`s are being copied, but your `Vec`s and array of `String`s cannot be—and so a move is attempted (and fails) instead.

Comment: The reason that `Vec` and `String` do not implement `Copy` is that they own heap allocations (which are not cheaply copyable).  If you're *sure* that you want new heap allocations (which is a relatively expensive operation), you can `clone` them instead.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for remanding,I don't know that before ..sorry

Comment: @Cyberlin: now that you know, could you update the post?

Answer (score 4):

In Rust all types fall into one of two categories:

- *copy*-semantic (if it implements the `Copy`-trait)
- *move*-semantic (if it does **not** implement the `Copy`-trait)

These semantics are implicitly employed by Rust whenever you e.g. assign a value to a variable. You can't choose it at the assignment. Instead, it depends only on the type in question. Therefore, whether `a` in the example below is moved or copied, depends entirely on what `T` is:

```rust
let a: T = /* some value */;
let b = a; // move or copy?
```

Also notice, that generic types are rather a set of similar types, than a single type by themselves (i.e. it is not a *concrete* type). For instance, you can't tell whether `[T;2]` is `Copy` or not, since it is not a concrete type (would need to know `T` first). Thus, `[&str;2]` and `[String;2]` are two totally different concrete types, and consequently one can be `Copy` and the other not.

To further elaborate, a concrete type can only be `Copy` if **all** constituting types are `Copy`. For instance, arrays `[T;2]` might be `Copy` (if `T` is too), `Vec` may never be `Copy` (independent of `T`).

So in your examples, when it does not compile due to move-semantics, you either have a `Vec` that is not `Copy` or `String` that is not, and any combinations with them can not be `Copy` either. Only if you combine `Copy`-types (arrays, ints, `&str`) you get copy-semantics, and your examples compile.

Also, this not an issue about ownership, because if you have copy-semantics you can just generate new values (by coping them) wherever you need, which gives you (fresh) ownership of these new values.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things here. First of all you are not changing the ownership in the working examples. You are merely borrowing their values. The difference in your not working examples is that in them you are actually changing the ownership.

As @eggyal correctly pointed out `String` and `Vec` don't implement `Copy` and that's important because **`Copy` is used automatically** when assigning another variable to a new variable. and in your working examples you have `i32` (default for numeric types) and `&str`(also known as a string slice) which both implement `Copy`.

Every string literal is initially a `&str`  and not a `String`. The `.to_string()` method in your example converts a `&str` into a `String`. If you want more in-depth information about the differences between `&str` and `String` I suggest you either check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/3786622) or read an article about it but what's most important in your case is that string slices point to a read-only portion of the memory making them effectively **immutable** and therefore safe for copying.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler nowadays is so good that it tells you the entire story. I compiled your code and got this wonderful error message:

```
   |
18 |     let mut a = vec![2, 4];
   |         ----- move occurs because `a` has type `Vec<i32>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
19 |     let b = a;
   |             - value moved here
20 |     println!("{:?}", a);
   |                      ^ value borrowed here after move
```