# Why would you convert from a string in Rust to a String?

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and comes from a python domain, I've just started learning rust, so I've 2 questions to ask. 1) Why are we defining "String" again (name: String) when already I have mentioned the datatype to be as "String" in my "struct Person". 2) What exactly is the use of from. Please could someone explain me in simple english.

```
fn main() {
struct Person {
    name: String,
}

// instantiate Person struct
let person = Person {
    name: String::from("Steve Austin"), //Why are we defining "string" again and "from"
};

// access value of name field in Person struct
println!("Person name = {}", person.name);
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are we defining "String" again (name: String) when already I have mentioned the datatype to be as "String" in my "struct Person". 2) What exactly is the use of from.

You're not *defining* anything, `String::from` is a static function (think classmethod), which *converts* to a string.

It's a bit like calling `str()` in Python.

The oddity here is that Rust has multiple string-adjacent types, and `String` is only one of them: an owned, heap-allocated, mutable, string buffer. Python doesn't really have an equivalent, `StringIO` is probably the closest relative (`strarray` would be if it existed, but it does not).

Meanwhile string literals are not owned heap-allocated strings, instead they are references to data stored in the rodata (or text) segment of the binary.

Python has nothing which really compares, because its strings are more or less always heap-allocated and created at runtime, they're just immutable. The closest general equivalent to `&str` would be a string version of `memoryview`, but it still lacks the lexical constraints, and the idea of a `'static` lifetime.

For more, see

- https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/str.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24159933/8182118
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, basically from what I have understood, when we are defining "name: String" in my struct then we are saying that only string should come here. But when we are doing this " name: String::from("Steve Austin")", then we are saying that allocate heap memory to string with value name(Steve Austin). "::from" is just assigning values from right to left. Right?

Comment: Kinda. In Python it's like defining a dataclass versus initialising it. ""::from" is just assigning values from right to left. Right?" from is just a function call no different from any other. But in struct initialisation (expression), `name:` is saying that you're assigning the RHS value to that name, in the struct, rather than a definition. In Python syntax it'd be something like `Person(name=str.from("Steve Austin")`.

Comment: Got it @Masklinn & I really appreciate you in connecting my issue with python syntax.

Comment: maybe this can help you understand it a bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/

Answer (score 4):

In Rust there's two kinds of strings: `str` and `String`. The former is a really lean construct and is passed around as a reference, like `&str`. These *cannot* be modified.<sup>1</sup> They also can't be copied, they're references, so they will always refer to the same value.

The reason they exist is because they are the "minimum viable string", they are the cheapest possible representation of textual data. This efficiency does have trade-offs.

A `String` can be modified if it's `mut`, and can also be copied, and later altered again. This makes them more suitable for properties that can and will change, or need to be computed at runtime.

Learning the difference here can be a bit bewildering if you're used to Python where strings are strings, but once you get a handle on it, you'll realize what's going on here.

`"x"` is a `&str` value, while `String::from("x")` is a `String` converted *from* that value. You can also do `"x".into()` if the type is well understood by the compiler, such as for a function argument or struct property.

Strings are also such a common thing that there's `to_string()` and `to_owned()`, both of which effectively do the same thing here on `&str` values.

If you want the best of both of these features, you can use `Cow<str>` which can encapsulate either an `&str` value, or a `String`, and you can convert from the "borrowed" value (`&str`) to an "owned" value via the `to_owned()` function.

These are more exotic, though, so I'd recommend only using them when you know what you're doing and need the performance gains they can offer.

--

<sup>1</sup> Treat these like `const char*` in C++, versus `std::string`. The former is compiled into *non-modifiable data* in the executable, while the other uses a buffer that can be dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `String::from()` is not needed at all, it will work just fine without:

```
struct Person<'a> {
  name: &'a str
}
fn main() {
  let person = Person {
    name: "Steve Austin"
  };
  println!("Person name = {}", person.name);
}
```

But it really depends on if your program would ever need to change `Person.name` and if you think that the struct should hold the data itself ("own" the data).

A `str` is a fixed string, it is stored in your executable and can be referenced in your program with a pointer `&` as a `&str` pointer. But it **can not** be modified.
In your case, `"Steve Austin"` can be used in your program as a `&str`.

In your example the `name` property is of type `String`. The contents of a String **can** be modified by your program because it lives in its own place in memory. This is where ownership comes in.

Rust will make sure that the `String` which is held by the `struct` lives long enough, by implicitly deriving both the lifetime of the `struct` and that of the `String`. Notice that to Rust, those are two different things. In your example, the `struct` really *holds* the data itself and so there is no question about what the lengths of the lifetimes should be.

In my example, Rust needs to be told the separate lifetimes for both the `struct` and the `&str`. Rust needs the `&str` to live (be present in memory) at least as long as the `struct`, because of the memory safety Rust offers via its borrow checker. This way the `struct` can not have a `&str` pointing to invalid memory (something that is not under control).

At first you might think that `String` in Rust is a pointer. But that is not the case. To Rust, **`String` represents the data itself**. When you want to reference that data, with a promise not to make modifications to it, you use a `&` (pointer). If you do want to make changes, you need to tell Rust your intention, and use a `&mut` (pointer to mutable data).

The difference of `str` and `String` in Rust will give you precise control over you program, and performance.