# How to build a str in Rust

Tags: arrays, string, rust

Suppose I have a `char` in the variable `c` and a positive `int` in the variable `n`.  I want to build the `str` containing `c` occurring `n` times.  How can I do it?

I tried building it as a `String`, and maybe I just got dizzy trying to read the documentation on strings, but I couldn't see how to convert it to a `str`.  But then if I'm trying to just build it as a `str` directly then I couldn't see how to do that either.

For context, here is the full function I'm trying to implement.  It takes a string and finds the longest sequence of consecutive characters (and breaks ties by taking the first that occurs).

```
pub fn longest_sequence(s: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    if s.len() == 0 { return None; }
    let mut current_c = s.as_bytes()[0] as char;
    let mut greatest_c = s.as_bytes()[0] as char;
    let mut current_num = 0;
    let mut greatest_num = 0;
    for ch in s.chars() {
        if current_c == ch {
            current_num += 1;
            if current_num > greatest_num {
                greatest_num = current_num;
                greatest_c = current_c;
            }
        } else {
            current_num = 1;
            current_c = ch;
        }
    }
    // Now build the output str ...
}
```

Comment: For your particular problem, you don't need to build a new string, note that you could return a substring of your original string `s`. Once you have your start/end indexes of the longest sequence, you just return `s[start..end]`

Comment: Note that `String`/`str` in Rust are designed to handle UTF-8, which makes how they work quite different than languages like C/C++. See this question for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str

Comment: @effect Right, so I tried something like that.  I didn't return a slice of the original string (because that seems hard, and it seems easier to just identify the character I want and its frequency, rather than tracking the indices at which they occur) but I tried making a new string and then returning a string slice of that.  But then I ran into ownership issues with that, that I don't fully understand.

Comment: Ok, if you want to do it that way, then you probably want to return a `Option<String>` instead of an `Option<&str>`. You can't return a `&str` reference to a `String` you create within the function, since the `String` goes out of scope at the end of the function, making your reference invalid.

Comment: @effect Ah ... wow, this ownership stuff ... ok, I think you're right then, maybe I should just do whatever it takes to slice the input string instead.  Ok, thank you!

Comment: @Addem Creating a string in other languages and returning a reference to it is undefined behaviour as well .. in general, creating a temporary variable and returning a reference to it is undefined behaviour. Rust just tells you that it is a problem ;)

Comment: *"but I couldn't see how to convert it to a `str`"* - to me, the more important question is why are you trying to do this? Why do you require a `str` as a return value? I agree with @Addem that returning a `String` would probably be the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of misconceptions about `str` vs `String`.

- `str` can never exist alone. It is always used as `&str` (or `Box<str>` or `*str`, but in your case those shouldn't matter).
- `&str` does not own any data. It is merely a reference to (parts of) another `String`.
- `String` actually holds data.
- So when you want to return **data**, use `String`; if you want to **reference existing data**, return `&str`.
- There **is no way** to convert a local `String` to a `&str`. Somewhere the data has to be stored, and `&str` doesn't store it. (for completeness sake: Yes you could leak it, but that would create a permanent string in memory that will never go away again)

So in your case there are two ways:

- Reference the input `&str`, because somewhere its data is already stored.
- Return a `String` instead.

As a side note: do not do `s.as_bytes()[0] as char`, as it **will not work** with UTF8-strings. Rust strings are defined as UTF8.

Here is one possible solution:

```rust
pub fn longest_sequence(s: &str) -> Option<&str> {
    let mut current_c = s.chars().next()?;
    let mut current_start = 0;
    let mut current_len = 0;
    let mut greatest: &str = "";
    let mut greatest_len = 0;
    for (pos, ch) in s.char_indices() {
        if current_c == ch {
            current_len += 1;
        } else {
            if greatest_len < current_len {
                greatest = &s[current_start..pos];
                greatest_len = current_len;
            }

            current_len = 1;
            current_c = ch;
            current_start = pos;
        }
    }

    if greatest_len < current_len {
        greatest = &s[current_start..];
    }

    Some(greatest)
}

pub fn main() {
    let s = "€€";

    let seq = longest_sequence(s);
    println!("{:?}", seq);
}
```

```
Some("")
```

Some explanations:

- No need to check for empty string. `s.chars().next()?` does so automatically.
- Use `s.chars().next()` instead of `s.as_bytes()[0] as char`, as the second one is not UTF8 compatible.
- I explicitely store `greatest_len` instead of using `greatest.len()` because `greatest.len()` is also not UTF8 compatible as it gives you the size of the string in **bytes**, not in **chars**.
- You stored the new largest string whenever a new char of the same value was found; I had to move it to the case where the char type changed (and once after the loop), because we **don't** yet know the end of the current char. Again, note that `&s[current_start..current_start+current_len]` wouldn't work, because `&s[ .. ]` wants indices in **bytes**, but `current_len` is in **chars**. So we need to wait for another char to know where the previous one ended.

---

Another solution, based on your code, would be:

```rust
pub fn longest_sequence(s: &str) -> Option<String> {
    let mut current_c = s.chars().next()?;
    let mut greatest_c = current_c;
    let mut current_num = 0;
    let mut greatest_num = 0;
    for ch in s.chars() {
        if current_c == ch {
            current_num += 1;
            if current_num > greatest_num {
                greatest_num = current_num;
                greatest_c = current_c;
            }
        } else {
            current_num = 1;
            current_c = ch;
        }
    }

    // Build the output String
    Some(std::iter::repeat(greatest_c).take(greatest_num).collect())
}

pub fn main() {
    let s = "€€";

    let seq = longest_sequence(s);
    println!("{:?}", seq);
}
```

```
Some("")
```

Comment: Interesting -- you're definitely right about some of my misconceptions.  I'll need to study your post for a minute, but this is definitely a big help, thank you!

Comment: @Addem *very* recommended watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDoqT-a6UFg I recommend the entire video, and in one section section it talks about what `String` vs `str` is behind the scenes, layed out in memory. For some people (like me) having it visual like that really makes it click, maybe that works for you as well.

Answer (score -6):

To convert a `String` to `&'static str` you need to leak it like this:

```rust
fn leak(s: String) -> &'static str {
    let ptr = s.as_str() as *const str;
    core::mem::forget(s);
    unsafe {&*ptr}
}
```

And `char` to `String`:

```rust
fn cts(c: char, n: usize) -> String {
    (0..n)
        .map(|_| c)
        .collect()
}
```

So `char` to `&'static str` basically will look like this:

```rust
fn conv(c: char, n: usize) -> &'static str {
    leak(cts(c, n))
}
```

I do not recommend to leak the `String` tho, just use it as is.

Comment: @Finomnis, calling `forget` basically does it. Using `Box::leak` is a wrong way. And no, I don’t create a pointer to the stack. I’ve also said that memory leak is unnecessary here.

Comment: @Miiao I stand corrected. I forgot that `s` already puts its data on the heap. My bad.

Comment: I still stand to the fact that this leaks memory every time this function is called, so I recommend against it.

Comment: @Finomnis, it’s ok. Sorry if my reply was rude. And yes, I agree that memory leak is a bad approach.

Comment: @Miiao: Why would `Box::leak` be wrong? Btw, you want `as *const str`, not `u8` to compile.

Comment: @Caesar It's not wrong per se, but it leaks the `String` itself, which internally references a `str`, so while it works, you then leaked two things while you would only have required to leak one.

Comment: Either way, if you really **want** to leak a `String`, imo the only 'correct' way to do it is through [`String::into_boxed_str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.into_boxed_str): `let s_static: &'static str = Box::leak(s.into_boxed_str());`

Comment: @Caesar, my bad. Well, `Box::leak` does almost exactly what `forget` does, but returns a `&'static mut` while we need `&'static`. It can be easily fixed using deref, and probably without overhead.

Comment: @Miiao `&'static mut` can be directly stored in `&'static` without any overhead.

Comment: I don’t want to focus on leaking `String`s anyway, I just wanted to show how to repeat something using iterators.

Comment: Ok after looking at godbolt, I agree that your 'leak' is the least-overhead way to leak a string. I apologize ;) Although your cast should say `as *const str` instead of `as *const u8`. Otherwise you get a compilation error.

Comment: Yeah, I haven’t done this for a long time. It’s a poor excuse probably, but I didn’t sleep well       Thanks for the conversation