# consider using a let binding to create a longer lived value when using as_str()

Tags: rust

When I using this code in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello").as_str();
    println!("slice: {}", s); 
}
```

the compiler shows error:

```
temporary value dropped while borrowed
creates a temporary value which is freed while still in userustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(2, 43): temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
main.rs(3, 27): borrow later used here
main.rs(2, 5): consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value: `let binding = String::from("hello");
`, `binding`
```

does the as_str did not copy the value? I think the `s` will live util the main function end. why still told that long live issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the as_str did not copy the value?

No, this is exactly the difference between `String` and `&str`. `String` **owns** the value, `&str` is only a reference. `&str` is incapable of owning a value, it only references the `String`. And because you didn't store the `String` in a variable, it gets dropped while the `&str` still exists, which leads to the error.

Your code is equivalent to this one:

```rust
fn main() {
    let x: String = String::from("hello");
    let s: &str = x.as_str();
    drop(x);
    println!("slice: {}", s);
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `x` because it is borrowed
 --> src\main.rs:4:10
  |
2 |     let x: String = String::from("hello");
  |         - binding `x` declared here
3 |     let s: &str = x.as_str();
  |                   ---------- borrow of `x` occurs here
4 |     drop(x);
  |          ^ move out of `x` occurs here
5 |     println!("slice: {}", s);
  |                           - borrow later used here
```

If you store the `String` in a variable, it works fine:

```
fn main() {
    let x: String = String::from("hello");
    let s: &str = x.as_str();
    println!("slice: {}", s);
}
```

```
slice: hello
```

More info about the difference of `String` and `str` can be found here: [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)