# What happens under the hood when String type gets casted to &str type in rust

Tags: string, rust, stack, heap-memory

To my understanding the String type is allocated on the heap in rust and the pointer and length of it on the stack. The &str type is allocated on the stack directly due to its fixed size.

Now if I us as_str() on a String type in becomes a &str type. Does that mean the the content of the String type which is on the heap gets copied to the stack? Or is it a reference to that content that is on the heap?

Comment: `&str` like `String` is a pointer to some memory, unlike `String` it does not carry `capacity` information and it does not own the allocation, it does *not* store the string data itself.

Comment: [Chapter 4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) has some good pictures on it specifically [4.3 The slice type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html) is relevant since `str` is a string *slice*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Rust's \`String\` and \`str\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)

Answer (score 0):

> The &str type is allocated on the stack directly due to its fixed size.

Like with `String`, the *pointer and length* -- the actual things that make up the type -- are stored on the stack, but in the case of `&str`, the pointed-to string data may live anywhere: if it came from a `String`, the data lives where the `String` owns it on the heap, while if it came from an array, it lives on the stack.

Roughly speaking, a `&str` is represented by

```rust
struct StrRef {
    data: *const u8,
    len: usize,
}
```

So this is constructed from a `String` by doing something like

```
let owned = String::from("hello");
let borrowed = StrRef {
    data: owned.as_ptr(), // via Deref<Target = str>,
    len: owned.len(),
};
```

More strictly speaking, `str` (without the `&`) is a [dynamically sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#dynamically-sized-types-dsts), which means that a reference to it (`&str`) is *wide* -- it stores both a pointer to the data and *some metadata*, which in the case of `str` and `[T]` is a `usize` representing the length.

This wide pointer ends up looking something like `StrRef` above, but the exact representation of wide pointers is (currently) not a stable part of the language; `str` and `[T]` are treated specially by the compiler, as is `dyn Trait` (where the metadata is a pointer to a vtable).