# Why can a `str` type be of any size (unknown size) while a `String` type size is supposedly known?

Tags: string, rust, heap-memory

I was learning *Rust* with a book and the following excerpt threw me a bit off:

*Also note that `&str` has the `&` in front of it because you need a reference to use a `str`. That's because of the reason we saw above: the stack needs to know the size, and a `str` can be of any length. So we access it with a `&`, a reference. The compiler knows the size of a reference's pointer, and it can then use the `&` to find where the `str` data is and read it. Also, because you use a `&` to interact with a `str`, you don't own it. But a `String` is an "owned" type.*

I understand that for variables of unknown size, you must place the data on the heap and then reference to it with a fixed-length pointer on the stack. My confusion lies with the statement that **`str` can be of any length**.

**Why can't a `String` type also be of unknown length at times and require the whole reference to data on heap approach?**

I understand that the book will probably dive deeper into the details later on, but I was wondering if someone could already provide some additional context for me, specifically regarding the question above? Any useful accompanying details regarding the `&str` and `String` types in *Rust*, that are good to know for a beginner to the language, are highly appreciated as well.

Comment: Wouldn't [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) answer your own question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like a slice `[T]`, `str` is a variably-sized type. (In fact, `str` is essentially a `[u8]` guaranteed to contain valid UTF-8.)

Variably-sized types are special. They do not implement the `Sized` trait. A reference to a variably-sized type is "fat": it doesn't just hold the address of the referenced thing, but also its size.

`str` therefore means "some area in memory which contains valid UTF-8 data". And `&str` is "the address and size of such an area".

---

`String` on the other hand is a struct with a fixed size. One of its members is a pointer to string data somewhere else (on the heap). Conceptually, a `String` *contains* a `&str` along with the unused capacity of the memory area. (In reality, a `String` is a wrapper around a `Vec<u8>` with UTF-8 guarantee, a `Vec<u8>` conceptually contains a `&[u8]` plus capacity but is really a raw pointer, size and capacity.)

The total memory required by a `String` is therefore still variable, but the part that is the `String` struct itself is known.

Why is it this way? Because the entire point of `String` is to *manage* a memory region containing string data, and it can't do that if it *is* the memory region containing string data.

---

An aside:

> I understand that for variables of unknown size, you must place the data on the heap

This is a misconception. The heap is the most obvious place to put variably-sized data, but

- string literals are placed in read-only memory,
- you can have a fixed-size buffer somewhere (global variable, local stack array) and put some variably-sized data inside as long as it fits,
- low-level, you can use some `alloca` equivalent to allocate variably-sized data on the stack.

Comment: If a *fat* reference can also contain additional information (the size of the data being pointed at), isn't it then fundamentally different to a *normal reference*? **What downsides do *fat* references have to *normal* ones?** Why wouldn't you always just use *fat* references that contain more information?

Comment: Exactly _because_ they contain more information. Therefore - have larger size, which for normal statically-determined (and therefore statically-sized) types is redundant.