# How to create a string literal

Tags: string, performance, rust

You just want to create a string literal like "Hello, world!" and print it out. How should you do this?

```
let str = "Hello, world!";
// or
let str = String::from("Hello, world!");
// or
let str = "Hello, world!".to_owned();
// or
let str = "Hello, world!".to_string();
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str ?

Comment: `str` is not a string literal in any of these cases. `"Hello, world!"` is. Reference: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/tokens.html#string-literals

Comment: @EugeneSh. Dunno what you mean but 'str' is just the name of the variable in this example.

Comment: @Heineken `str` is a variable. The object formed via the code `"Hello, world!"` is the string literal. Your first example is that `str` stores a reference to the literal. Since they are object tied to the code, asking "how to create" one is very weird and a symptom of an XY problem.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Maybe I should have named this "Hello, world in Rust"? I still feel like it's obvious what this question is about. There are many ways of creating a string and printing it out, what's the difference?

Comment: @Heineken The point they're trying to make is that "string literal" has a specific meaning in Rust, and isn't interchangeable with "string". In any case, it's not clear what your question is. Are you asking what the difference between `str` and `String` is? Or are asking about how to idiomatically create a `String` from a `&str`? Or something else?

Comment: @Heineken Read Ivan C's linked answer for the difference between a `str` and `String`. In your example, the first `str` is a reference to a string stored in the program's read only memory section. The rest allocate owned strings, using various traits and methods.

Comment: The first one is an `&str`. All other three are equivalent ways to convert `&str` to `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *You just want to create a string literal like "Hello, world!" and print it out. How should you do this?*

```
println!("Hello, world!");
```

There's no need even for a variable.

`"Hello, world!"` is the string literal stored as part of the Rust binary. It is immutable. It is distinct from the `str` and `String` types.

Let's go through your four lines of code.

## `let s = "Hello, world!";`

`s` contains a [`str`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html), aka a "string slice", initialized with a string literal. It is a primitive type built into Rust. This is basically a pointer to the `H` in `"Hello, world!"` and a length. Since it points to an immutable string literal, a `s` cannot change the string. It can only change its start and length.

For example, [`trim`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim) works by moving the starting pointer and length. The string literal remains unchanged.

```
// s points at the first "\t" and has a length of 9.
let s = "\t\nHello\t\n";

// trimmed points at "H" and has a length of 5.
let trimmed = s.trim()

println!(s) // "\t\nHello\t\n"
println!(trimmed) // "Hello"

// Both s and trimmed point at the same string literal.
// "\t\nHello\t\n"
//  ^   ^
//  |   t----
//  s------------
```

## `let s = String::from("Hello, world!");`

`s` contains a [`String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) initialized with a string literal. This is a struct with its own memory for a copy of the string literal. This allows you to make changes to the contents; you're changing the copy.

## `let s = "Hello, world!".to_owned();`

`s` contains a `String`. [`to_owned`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html#tymethod.to_owned) is used to created owned data from borrowed data, usually by cloning it. It works on anything with the [ToOwned trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.ToOwned.html).

When [called on a string literal (a `str`)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#impl-ToOwned-for-str), it returns a String.

## `let s = "Hello, world!".to_string();`

`s` contains a `String`. `to_string` is part of the [ToString trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#tymethod.to_string). It converts a value to a String. Under the hood, its probably equivalent to `String::from`.

Comment: The last pararaph got it backwards the [blanket implementation of `ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html#impl-ToString-for-T) is using `Display` to implement itself, not the other way round.

Comment: @cafce25 Thx, I'll just skip it.