# Rust string manipulation, flow control improvements

Tags: string, rust, conventions, flow-control

I am new to the language and currently learning from the rust programming book.
I am wondering if there are any better way to improve my code. Especially the 2 pop (not sure if its the best practice)

Here is the code in question:

```
fn converttemp() {
    //user input
    println!("Please input temp (ex: 60F): ");
    let mut temp = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut temp)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    //getting the  unit at the end of the string
    let unit = temp.trim().chars().last().unwrap();

    //removing \n and unit character
    temp.pop();
    temp.pop();

    //parse string to float
    let mut val: c_float = temp.parse().unwrap();

    //temp conversion control flow
    if unit == 'f' || unit == 'F' {
        val = (val - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0;
        println!("{temp}F to C = {val}C");
    } else if unit == 'c' || unit == 'C' {
        val = val * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;
        println!("{temp}C to F = {val}F");
    } else {
        println!("error");
    }
}
```

I am a little confused at &str when I store the popped string but it retains String datatype when it is not stored. I am also a little confused on Option, for my case particularly Option. I had to. find workarounds when the data ended up being these.

edit:
when I store the new popped string

```
let val = temp.pop();
```

`val is Option<Char>`

```
let unit = temp.trim().chars().last();
```

`unit is Option<Char>`

What is the major difference between String and &str

All I know is that one is mutable and one is immutable

Comment: Could you try to clarify what the question is about? What does "when I store the popped string" mean? Also, with respect to `Option`, you're referring to `.last()` returning `Option`?

Comment: Thanks. for replying! Yes, that is what I meant, is there a way to use Option<Char>? I only know that it has the Some property which can have a null value? (I might be incorrect) with it but did not quite understand the use of it, and why it is returned instead of Char

Comment: With respect to `String` vs. `str`, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str) answer your question? With respect to `Option`: Consider what happens if `temp` is the empty string ``. Then `.pop()` can't have a value, which is represented as `Option<Char>::None`. Same goes for `unit`: If `temp` is empty, `last()` can't have a value (because the iterator from `chars()` doesn't yield even one `char`), which would also be represented as `Option<Char>::None`.

Comment: This is actually really helpful (the link and your detailed explanation). Thanks for clearing up my misconceptions! Cheers and Happy New Year!

Comment: [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=cd0c6b940199f56ab783af12fa107858) is a slightly cleaned-up version of your function. If this question has been answered, be a good sport and close it, so people aren't attracted to it unnecessarily.

Comment: You could also use `str::split_at` to split the unit from the number, and use a string pattern on the former, [for slightly more simplification](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7ebc57b98ac37d6ea52c9e88d5f9d188).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you guys for improving my code. I don't know why I did not think to use split_at for my implementation. On another note, how do I close a question? I thought someone must vote close a question.

Comment: The best option is for whoever answered it to post an actual answer. If they don't want to, you may be able to answer your own question.